# How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation, addition

I need to concatenate two `String` arrays in Java.

```
void f(String[] first, String[] second) {
    String[] both = ???
}
```

Which is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Bytes.concat from Guava

Comment: I see a lot of responses here but the question is so worded ('easiest way' ?) that it does not allow to indicate the best answer...

Comment: Dozens of answers here are copying the data into a new array because that is what was asked for - but copying data when not strictly necessary is a bad thing to do especially in Java. Instead, keep track of the indexes and use the two arrays as if they were joined. I have added a solution illustrating the technique.

Comment: The simplest is that you probably shouldn't be using arrays in the first place, you should be using ArrayLists, and your output should be an ArrayList.  Once you've made these your pre-condition, the operation is built-in--first.addAll(second).  The only case where this wouldn't be pretty much automatic is when your arrays are non-object types (int, long, double, ...), in that case intrinsic arrays can have a big advantage over ArrayLists--but for Strings--meh

Comment: The fact that a question like this currently has 50 different answers makes me wonder why Java never got a simple `array1 + array2` concatenation.

Comment: You can do it perfectly well and very efficiently in two lines of standard Java (see my answer), so there is not an awful lot to be gained by having a single method to do it. All of these weird-and-wonderful solutions are a bit of a waste of time.

Comment: Such questions just remind you how bad is java with array and collection manipulations in general..

Answer (score 1286):

I found a one-line solution from the good old Apache Commons Lang library.
 [`ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)

Code:

```
String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

Comment: How is it "cheating" if it answers the question? Sure, having an extra dependency is probably overkill for this specific situation, but no harm is done in calling out that it exists, especially since there's so many excellent bits of functionality in Apache Commons.

Comment: I agree, this isn't really answering the question.  High level libraries can be great, but if you want to learn an efficient way to do it, you want to look at the code the library method is using.  Also, in many situations, you can't just through another library in the product on the fly.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. POJO solutions have also been provided, but if the OP is using Apache Commons in their program already (altogether possible considering its popularity) he may still not know this solution. Then he wouldn't be "adding a dependency for this one method," but would be making better use of an existing library.

Comment: @Outlaw Programmer, I think most people would rather have the simplest possible method. Java is verbose enough already.

Comment: I'm using commons-lang-2.4.jar. There's no generic version of addAll() in ArrayUtils. So I had to cast the returned Object[] to String[] explicitly.

Comment: you could have given the reference to the answer as you did, and pasted the implementation from the source. that would have solved the issues above about the "cheating" aspect of your answer.

Comment: The OP asked for the easiest way to solve the problem. This really is the easiest way, but only under the assumption that the library is already present, which is not mentioned in the question. Otherwise it is actually much easier to copy and paste several lines of code instead of copying just one and then messing with adding a separate library to the project.

Comment: If you are always worried about not adding a library for a single method, no new libraries will ever get added. Given the excellent utilities present in Apache Commons, I highly recommend adding it when the very first use case arises.

Comment: @Antti Sykäri sorry for asking I'm a newbie to Java, why is  `(String[])` is used in `String[] both = (String[])ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);` without it will it not combine the 2 arrays

Comment: using apache commons should never be called 'cheating' i question the sanity of developers who thing its an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: ArrayUtils can be downloaded at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: @OutlawProgrammer I rarely hesitate to add a dependency to my application if it makes the code simpler and means I have less to maintain. Most people don't work under the kinds of constraints that necessitate worrying about adding a dependency. (I.e., they have plenty of disk space, don't need the absolutely fastest in everything, etc.)

Comment: These kind of solutions are helping to people working alone on their hobby projects but has no contribution when you are working on a company project or basically a project you just should not add a new dependency to concat two arrays.

Comment: One doubt, can it handle null, like if null is there response is null or blank string arr if other one is blank?

Comment: This should not be the number one answer. The answer using a external library for something so trivial is overkill.

Comment: @JohnnyLim, how do you cast the Object[] to String[] when using `ArrayUtils.addAll(Arr1, Arr2)`? My Arr1 / Arr2 is   initialized as `List<Object> obj = new ArrayList<>()`, with content from double, string etc.

Answer (score 791):

Here's a simple method that will concatenate two arrays and return the result:

```
public <T> T[] concatenate(T[] a, T[] b) {
    int aLen = a.length;
    int bLen = b.length;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] c = (T[]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), aLen + bLen);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);

    return c;
}
```

Note that it will not work with primitive data types, only with object types.

The following slightly more complicated version works with both object and primitive arrays. It does this by using `T` instead of `T[]` as the argument type.

It also makes it possible to concatenate arrays of two different types by picking the most general type as the component type of the result.

```
public static <T> T concatenate(T a, T b) {
    if (!a.getClass().isArray() || !b.getClass().isArray()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    Class<?> resCompType;
    Class<?> aCompType = a.getClass().getComponentType();
    Class<?> bCompType = b.getClass().getComponentType();

    if (aCompType.isAssignableFrom(bCompType)) {
        resCompType = aCompType;
    } else if (bCompType.isAssignableFrom(aCompType)) {
        resCompType = bCompType;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int aLen = Array.getLength(a);
    int bLen = Array.getLength(b);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T result = (T) Array.newInstance(resCompType, aLen + bLen);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, aLen, bLen);        

    return result;
}
```

Here is an example:

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }, concatenate(new int[] { 1, 2 }, new int[] { 3 }));
Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Number[] { 1, 2, 3f }, concatenate(new Integer[] { 1, 2 }, new Number[] { 3f }));
```

Comment: I like this suggestion since it is less dependent on the latest Java versions.  In my projects I'm often stuck using older versions of Java or CLDC profiles where some of the facilities like those mentioned by Antti are not available.

Comment: The following line will break the generic part: concatenate(new String[]{"1"},new Object[] { new Object()})

Comment: would be nice not to have to use the @SuppressWarnings annotation - I'll post a solution for that below.

Comment: +1 for `Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), aLen + bLen);`. I've surprisingly never seen that before. @beaudet I think the annotation is fine here, considering why it is being suppressed.

Comment: ha, call me a purist but I prefer clean code that doesn't require suppression of warnings in order to remove warnings

Comment: There's a difference between semantic warnings and "I'm using raw memory like I would in C, so turn off your safety since I know what I'm doing"
"I'm being unsafe" isn't a semantic warning suppression. It's a "I'm going lower level on purpose now, so stop whining." Feel lucky, as Swift 5 removed suppressors. Java, unlike Swift, is still made for programmers who aren't afraid of doing their own programming

Comment: The second version does not work with an array of strings as it's first and an array of long (primitives) as it's second.

Answer (score 590):

Using [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) in Java 8:

```
String[] both = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b))
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Or like this, using `flatMap`:

```
String[] both = Stream.of(a, b).flatMap(Stream::of)
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

To do this for a generic type you have to use reflection:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
T[] both = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b)).toArray(
    size -> (T[]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), size));
```

Comment: How efficient is this?

Comment: Worth a read: https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html

tl;dr - streams could be performant or not, it depends on what you're doing with them and the constraints of the problem (isn't this always the answer? lol)

Comment: Yeah, it's a risky solution from the performance point of view. It might be fast, but I wouldn't bet my application's performance on it ;)

Comment: Additionally, if *a* or *b* are arrays of primitive types, their streams will need to be `.boxed()` so they are of type `Stream` rather than e.g. `IntStream` which cannot be passed as a parameter to `Stream.concat`.

Comment: @Will Hardwick-Smith: no, you only have to pick the right stream class, e.g. if `a` and `b` are `int[]`, use `int[] both = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b)).toArray();`

Comment: @Supuhstar: It is probably not as fast as `System.arrayCopy`. But not particularly slow either. You probably have to do this a *very* many times with *huge* arrays in *really* performance sensitive contexts for the execution time difference to matter.

Comment: I wonder which is faster and more memory efficient: the concat method or flatMap? Or are they the same under the hood?

Comment: The latter solution is nice because it can be used for more than 2 arrays unlike most (if not all) the other answers.

Comment: @SinaMadani with all known implementations, the variant using `concat` will be faster and need less memory, because it can predict the resulting array size beforehand and will create and fill only one array. In contrast, the `flatMap` based solution will have to use a resizable buffer internally, with at least one final copying step.

Comment: Is it possible to make it works for generic type (like in the answer above)? Something like `T[] both = Stream.of(a, b).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(T[]::new);` Looks like `T[]::new` isn't allowed cause of type erasure...

Comment: @ArtsiomChapialiou: You can, but it's not so pretty. You have to use reflection to create the array, and thus get an unchecked cast. I added that to the solution text.

Answer (score 500):

It's possible to write a fully generic version that can even be extended to concatenate any number of arrays. This versions require Java 6, as they use [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T[],%20int%29)

Both versions avoid creating any intermediary `List` objects and use `System.arraycopy()` to ensure that copying large arrays is as fast as possible.

For two arrays it looks like this:

```
public static <T> T[] concat(T[] first, T[] second) {
  T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
  System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
  return result;
}
```

And for a arbitrary number of arrays (>= 1) it looks like this:

```
public static <T> T[] concatAll(T[] first, T[]... rest) {
  int totalLength = first.length;
  for (T[] array : rest) {
    totalLength += array.length;
  }
  T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, totalLength);
  int offset = first.length;
  for (T[] array : rest) {
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, offset, array.length);
    offset += array.length;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @djBO: for primitive-typed arrays you'd need to make an overload for each type: just copy the code and replace each `T` with `byte` (and lose the `<T>`).

Comment: can you plese tell me how to use <T> operator type in my class?

Comment: I'd add this to the beginning, just to be defensive.         if (first == null)
        {
            if (second == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return second;
        }
        if (second == null)
        {
            return first;
        }

Comment: @djBo: what about:`ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(array1.length + array2.length); buffer.put(array1); buffer.put(array2); return buffer.array();`

Comment: There's a bug in this approach which becomes apparent if you invoke these functions with arrays of different component types, for example `concat(ai, ad)`, where `ai` is `Integer[]` and `ad` is `Double[]`. (In this case, the type parameter `<T>` is resolved to `<? extends Number>` by the compiler.) The array created by `Arrays.copyOf` will have the component type of the first array, i.e. `Integer` in this example. When the function is about to copy the second array, an `ArrayStoreException` will be thrown. The solution is to have an additional `Class<T> type` parameter.

Comment: @BrettOkken: yes - you are correct. I don't know why I suggested it... (probably because I had just written code to concatentate byte arrays...)

Answer (score 207):

Or with the beloved [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArrays.html#concat(T%5B%5D,%20T%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Class)):

```
String[] both = ObjectArrays.concat(first, second, String.class);
```

Also, there are versions for primitive arrays:

- `Booleans.concat(first, second)`
- `Bytes.concat(first, second)`
- `Chars.concat(first, second)`
- `Doubles.concat(first, second)`
- `Shorts.concat(first, second)`
- `Ints.concat(first, second)`
- `Longs.concat(first, second)`
- `Floats.concat(first, second)`

Comment: As much as I love Guava, the method from Apache Commons deals better with nullables.

Comment: While it is good to use libraries, it's unfortunate that the problem has been abstracted away.  Therefore the underlying solution remains elusive.

Comment: Whats the problem with abstraction? Dunno what's the deal with reinventing the wheel here, if you want to learn the problem the check the source or read on it. Professional code should be using high-level libraries, much better if it's developed inside Google!

Comment: @RaviWallau Could you link to the class that does this?

Comment: @SébastienTromp It is the top solution for this question - ArrayUtils.

Comment: I don't advise to add Guava into a project only to concatenate arrays, it's big and it has a serious lack of modularity. @BrenoSalgado "much better if it's developed inside Google" I strongly disagree with that.

Comment: It's crazy that the JDK doesn't have a method like this.

Comment: @RaviWallau Of course, the Guava nullability behavior is [by design](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained), so it really depends on whether you're trying to avoid `null`s or not, and whether it would be an error for the calling site to see a `null` in the first place.  "For [reasons mentioned on the linked page], many of Guava's utilities are designed to fail fast in the presence of null rather than allow nulls to be used, so long as there is a null-friendly workaround available."

Answer (score 181):

You can append the two arrays in two lines of code.

```
String[] both = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
System.arraycopy(second, 0, both, first.length, second.length);
```

This is a fast and efficient solution and will work for primitive types as well as the two methods involved are overloaded.

You should avoid solutions involving ArrayLists, streams, etc as these will need to allocate temporary memory for no useful purpose.

You should avoid `for` loops for large arrays as these are not efficient. The built in methods use block-copy functions that are extremely fast.

Comment: This is one of the best solutions.  100% standard Java.  Fast/efficient.  Should get more upvotes!

Comment: It may be efficient, but is a bit of a mess compared to what you might expect: `both = array1 + array2`

Answer (score 61):

Using the Java API:

```
String[] f(String[] first, String[] second) {
    List<String> both = new ArrayList<String>(first.length + second.length);
    Collections.addAll(both, first);
    Collections.addAll(both, second);
    return both.toArray(new String[both.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Simply, but inefficient as it make an array for ArrayList and then generate another for toArray method. But still valid as it's simple to read.

Comment: applicable for Strings and objects (as question wants), but there is no addAll method for primary types (as ints)

Comment: As elaborated in [this article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/), using `both.toArray(new String[0])` will be faster than `both.toArray(new String[both.size()])`, even if it contradicts our naive intuition. That’s why it is so important to measure the actual performance when optimizing. Or just use the simpler construct, when the advantage of the more complicated variant can’t be proven.

Answer (score 45):

A solution **100% old java** and **without** `System.arraycopy` (not available in GWT client for example):

```
static String[] concat(String[]... arrays) {
    int length = 0;
    for (String[] array : arrays) {
        length += array.length;
    }
    String[] result = new String[length];
    int pos = 0;
    for (String[] array : arrays) {
        for (String element : array) {
            result[pos] = element;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: reworked mine for File[], but it's the same. Thanks for your solution

Comment: Probably quite inefficient though.

Comment: You might want to add `null` checks.  And perhaps set some of your variables to `final`.

Comment: @TrippKinetics `null` checks would hide NPE's rather than showing them and using final for local vars doesn't have any benefit (yet).

Comment: Personally I would use normal `for` loops with an index rather than `for-each` here. It's unlikely to the extreme that this will be refactored to using lists (you'd just write another method) and for-each will very likely be slower than direct array access through indexing. Nitpick: `pos` should be defined within the scope first `for` loop, not outside it.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes I think you will find (if you benchmark it, which I have) that the for-each runs in the same time as the indexed loop on late versions of Java. The optimizer takes care of it.

Answer (score 35):

I've recently fought problems with excessive memory rotation. If a and/or b are known to be commonly empty, here is another adaption of silvertab's code (generified too):

```
private static <T> T[] concatOrReturnSame(T[] a, T[] b) {
    final int alen = a.length;
    final int blen = b.length;
    if (alen == 0) {
        return b;
    }
    if (blen == 0) {
        return a;
    }
    final T[] result = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.
            newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), alen + blen);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, alen);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, alen, blen);
    return result;
}
```

Edit: A previous version of this post stated that array re-usage like this shall be clearly documented. As Maarten points out in the comments it would in general be better to just remove the if statements, thus voiding the need for having documentation. But then again, those if statements were the whole point of this particular optimization in the first place. I'll leave this answer here, but be wary!

Comment: this however means that you are returning the same array and changing a value on the returned array changes the value in the same position of the input array returned.

Comment: Yes - see comment at the end of my post regarding array re-usage. The maintenance overhead imposed by this solution was worth it in our particular case, but defensive copying should probably be used in most cases.

Comment: Lorenzo / volley, can you explain which part in the code that cause array re-usage? I thought `System.arraycopy` copies the content of the array?

Comment: A caller would normally expect a call to concat() to return a newly allocated array. If either a or b is null, concat() will however return one of the arrays passed into it. This re-usage is what may be unexpected. (Yep, arraycopy only does copying. The re-usage comes from returning either a or b directly.)

Comment: Code should be as much self explanatory as possible. People reading the code should not have to lookup the JavaDoc of a called function to find out that it does one thing for one particular condition and something else for another. In short: you can generally not fix design problems like these with a comment. Just leaving the two `if` statements out would be the easiest fix.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I agree. This method was used at a very specific location to fix a very specific problem identified using profiling. I'll edit the comment about JavaDoc.

Comment: Try using that on char[] = {'a'} :/

Answer (score 27):

The [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org) library has an array wrapper class that equips arrays with handy methods like concatenation.

```
import static fj.data.Array.array;
```

...and then

```
Array<String> both = array(first).append(array(second));
```

To get the unwrapped array back out, call

```
String[] s = both.array();
```

Answer (score 27):

```
ArrayList<String> both = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(first));
both.addAll(Arrays.asList(second));

both.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: The answer is great but a tiny bit broken. To make it perfect you should pass to toArray() an array of the type you need. In the above example, the code should be: both.toArray(new String[0])            See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042434/converting-arrayliststring-to-string-in-java

Comment: Don't know why this answer isn't rated higher... though it does seem to need the change suggested by @RonenRabinovici

Comment: Or better, without unnecessary allocation of zero-length array: `both.toArray(new String[both.size()])` ;)

Comment: @Honza [recommended read](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/)

Comment: Hi @Honza, possible to do the same to return a primitive integer array in 3 lines?

Answer (score 20):

Another way with Java8 using Stream

```
  public String[] concatString(String[] a, String[] b){ 
    Stream<String> streamA = Arrays.stream(a);
    Stream<String> streamB = Arrays.stream(b);
    return Stream.concat(streamA, streamB).toArray(String[]::new); 
  }
```

Answer (score 17):

Here's an adaptation of silvertab's solution, with generics retrofitted:

```
static <T> T[] concat(T[] a, T[] b) {
    final int alen = a.length;
    final int blen = b.length;
    final T[] result = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.
            newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), alen + blen);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, alen);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, alen, blen);
    return result;
}
```

NOTE: See [Joachim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java/784842#784842) for a Java 6 solution. Not only does it eliminate the warning; it's also shorter, more efficient and easier to read!

Comment: You can suppress the warning for this method, but other than that there isn't much you can do.  Arrays and generics don't really mix.

Comment: The unchecked warning can be eliminated if you use Arrays.copyOf(). See my answer for an implementation.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score 15):

You could try converting it into a `ArrayList` and use the `addAll` method then convert back to an array.

```
List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(first));
  list.addAll(Arrays.asList(second));
  String[] both = list.toArray();
```

Comment: Good solution--would be better if the code was refactored to avoid arrays altogether in favor of ArrayLists, but that's outside the control of the "Answer" and up to the questioner.

Comment: I count that it requires 4 additional temporary objects to work.

Comment: @rghome, at least it doesn't require additional library to implement such simple task

Answer (score 13):

If you use this way so you no need to import any third party class.

If you want concatenate `String`

**Sample code for concate two String Array**

```
public static String[] combineString(String[] first, String[] second){
        int length = first.length + second.length;
        String[] result = new String[length];
        System.arraycopy(first, 0, result, 0, first.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
        return result;
    }
```

If you want concatenate `Int`

**Sample code for concate two Integer Array**

```
public static int[] combineInt(int[] a, int[] b){
        int length = a.length + b.length;
        int[] result = new int[length];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
        return result;
    }
```

**Here is Main method**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String [] first = {"a", "b", "c"};
            String [] second = {"d", "e"};

            String [] joined = combineString(first, second);
            System.out.println("concatenated String array : " + Arrays.toString(joined));

            int[] array1 = {101,102,103,104};
            int[] array2 = {105,106,107,108};
            int[] concatenateInt = combineInt(array1, array2);

            System.out.println("concatenated Int array : " + Arrays.toString(concatenateInt));

        }
    }
```

We can use this way also.

Answer (score 12):

Please forgive me for adding yet another version to this already long list. I looked at every answer and decided that I really wanted a version with just one parameter in the signature. I also added some argument checking to benefit from early failure with sensible info in case of unexpected input.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] concat(T[]... inputArrays) {
  if(inputArrays.length < 2) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("inputArrays must contain at least 2 arrays");
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < inputArrays.length; i++) {
    if(inputArrays[i] == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("inputArrays[" + i + "] is null");
    }
  }

  int totalLength = 0;

  for(T[] array : inputArrays) {
    totalLength += array.length;
  }

  T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(inputArrays[0].getClass().getComponentType(), totalLength);

  int offset = 0;

  for(T[] array : inputArrays) {
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, offset, array.length);

    offset += array.length;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I'd sum up the length in the same loop where you are doing your null check--but this is a really good summary of the other answers here.  I believe it even handles intrinsic types like "int" without changing them to Integer objects which is really the ONLY reason to deal with them as arrays rather than just changing everything to ArrayLists.  Also your method could take 2 arrays and a (...) parameter so the caller knows he needs to pass in at least two arrays before he runs it and sees the error, but that complicates the looping code....

Answer (score 11):

Using Java 8+ streams you can write the following function:

```
private static String[] concatArrays(final String[]... arrays) {
    return Arrays.stream(arrays)
         .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
         .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This should be one-liner.

```
public String [] concatenate (final String array1[], final String array2[])
{
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(array1), Stream.of(array2)).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This works, but you need to insert your own error checking.

```
public class StringConcatenate {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Create two arrays to concatenate and one array to hold both
        String[] arr1 = new String[]{"s","t","r","i","n","g"};
        String[] arr2 = new String[]{"s","t","r","i","n","g"};
        String[] arrBoth = new String[arr1.length+arr2.length];

        // Copy elements from first array into first part of new array
        for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
            arrBoth[i] = arr1[i];
        }

        // Copy elements from second array into last part of new array
        for(int j = arr1.length;j < arrBoth.length;j++){
            arrBoth[j] = arr2[j-arr1.length];
        }

        // Print result
        for(int k = 0; k < arrBoth.length; k++){
            System.out.print(arrBoth[k]);
        }

        // Additional line to make your terminal look better at completion!
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It's probably not the most efficient, but it doesn't rely on anything other than Java's own API.

Comment: +1. It would be better to replace the second `for` loop with that: `for(int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){arrBoth[arr1.length+j] = arr2[j];}`

Comment: Use `String[] arrBoth = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length + arr2.length)` to skip the first `for` loop.  Saves time proportional to size of `arr1`.

Answer (score 7):

Here a possible implementation in working code of the pseudo code solution written by silvertab.

Thanks silvertab!

```java
public class Array {

   public static <T> T[] concat(T[] a, T[] b, ArrayBuilderI<T> builder) {
      T[] c = builder.build(a.length + b.length);
      System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
      System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
      return c;
   }
}
```

Following next is the builder interface.

Note: A builder is necessary because in java it is not possible to do

`new T[size]`

due to generic type erasure:

```java
public interface ArrayBuilderI<T> {

   public T[] build(int size);
}
```

Here a concrete builder implementing the interface, building a `Integer` array:

```java
public class IntegerArrayBuilder implements ArrayBuilderI<Integer> {

   @Override
   public Integer[] build(int size) {
      return new Integer[size];
   }
}
```

And finally the application / test:

```java
@Test
public class ArrayTest {

   public void array_concatenation() {
      Integer a[] = new Integer[]{0,1};
      Integer b[] = new Integer[]{2,3};
      Integer c[] = Array.concat(a, b, new IntegerArrayBuilder());
      assertEquals(4, c.length);
      assertEquals(0, (int)c[0]);
      assertEquals(1, (int)c[1]);
      assertEquals(2, (int)c[2]);
      assertEquals(3, (int)c[3]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Wow! lot of complex answers here including some simple ones that depend on external dependencies. how about doing it like this:

```
String [] arg1 = new String{"a","b","c"};
String [] arg2 = new String{"x","y","z"};

ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(arg1));
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(arg2));
String [] concatedArgs = temp.toArray(new String[arg1.length+arg2.length]);
```

Comment: ..But inefficient and slow.

Answer (score 6):

A generic static version that uses the high performing System.arraycopy without requiring a @SuppressWarnings annotation:

```
public static <T> T[] arrayConcat(T[] a, T[] b) {
    T[] both = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + b.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, both, a.length, b.length);
    return both;
}
```

I ran some performance tests using the different solutions suggested in the responses here.

[image: Array Concatenation Performance by Method and Data Type]

One million iterations were performed and the average taken for the values in the table below.  Tests were run on Ubuntu running on top of WSL 2. Fill Type refers to the nature of the data contained in the two 1000 element arrays that were concatenated together.

| Data Type | Fill Type | System.arraycopy | For loop | Stream.concat | Guava ObjectArrays.concat | Apache Commons Lang ArrayUtils.addAll |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Integer | EMPTY | 928 ns | 2680 ns | 3252 ns | 547 ns | 556 ns |
| Integer | SAME_VALUE | 632 ns | 3282 ns | 4787 ns | 545 ns | 582 ns |
| Integer | RANDOM | 625 ns | 3264 ns | 4790 ns | 557 ns | 547 ns |
| Double | EMPTY | 616 ns | 2663 ns | 3239 ns | 548 ns | 561 ns |
| Double | SAME_VALUE | 632 ns | 3259 ns | 4793 ns | 559 ns | 598 ns |
| Double | RANDOM | 715 ns | 3511 ns | 5092 ns | 575 ns | 544 ns |
| String | EMPTY | 629 ns | 2744 ns | 3183 ns | 547 ns | 536 ns |
| String | SAME_VALUE | 642 ns | 3242 ns | 4735 ns | 567 ns | 539 ns |
| String | RANDOM | 619 ns | 3308 ns | 4948 ns | 545 ns | 549 ns |

It appears that the Google and Apache codes are quite close with System.arraycopy based approaches coming in 3rd.  The *for loop* and Streamconcat approaches were far behind the other three.

Answer (score 5):

A simple variation allowing the joining of more than one array:

```
public static String[] join(String[]...arrays) {

    final List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String[] array : arrays) {
        output.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    }

    return output.toArray(new String[output.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a converted function for a String array:

```
public String[] mergeArrays(String[] mainArray, String[] addArray) {
    String[] finalArray = new String[mainArray.length + addArray.length];
    System.arraycopy(mainArray, 0, finalArray, 0, mainArray.length);
    System.arraycopy(addArray, 0, finalArray, mainArray.length, addArray.length);

    return finalArray;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about simply

```
public static class Array {

    public static <T> T[] concat(T[]... arrays) {
        ArrayList<T> al = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T[] one : arrays)
            Collections.addAll(al, one);
        return (T[]) al.toArray(arrays[0].clone());
    }
}
```

And just do `Array.concat(arr1, arr2)`. As long as `arr1` and `arr2` are of the same type, this will give you another array of the same type containing both arrays.

Comment: For performance reasons, I would pre-compute the ArrayList's final size because ArrayList, by definition, allocates a new array and copies its elements every time the current array is full. Otherwise I would go straight for LinkedList which does not suffer such problem

Answer (score 4):

```
public String[] concat(String[]... arrays)
{
    int length = 0;
    for (String[] array : arrays) {
        length += array.length;
    }
    String[] result = new String[length];
    int destPos = 0;
    for (String[] array : arrays) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, destPos, array.length);
        destPos += array.length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my slightly improved version of Joachim Sauer's concatAll. It can work on Java 5 or 6, using Java 6's System.arraycopy if it's available at runtime. This method (IMHO) is perfect for Android, as it work on Android <9 (which doesn't have System.arraycopy) but will use the faster method if possible.

```
  public static <T> T[] concatAll(T[] first, T[]... rest) {
    int totalLength = first.length;
    for (T[] array : rest) {
      totalLength += array.length;
    }
    T[] result;
    try {
      Method arraysCopyOf = Arrays.class.getMethod("copyOf", Object[].class, int.class);
      result = (T[]) arraysCopyOf.invoke(null, first, totalLength);
    } catch (Exception e){
      //Java 6 / Android >= 9 way didn't work, so use the "traditional" approach
      result = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(first.getClass().getComponentType(), totalLength);
      System.arraycopy(first, 0, result, 0, first.length);
    }
    int offset = first.length;
    for (T[] array : rest) {
      System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, offset, array.length);
      offset += array.length;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Good general idea, but to anyone implementing: I'd prefer a copyOf and non-copyOf versions than one that does both by way of reflection.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to think about the question. To concatenate two or more arrays, one have to do is to list all elements of each arrays, and then build a new array. This sounds like create a `List<T>` and then calls `toArray` on it. Some other answers uses `ArrayList`, and that's fine. But how about implement our own? It is not hard:

```
private static <T> T[] addAll(final T[] f, final T...o){
    return new AbstractList<T>(){

        @Override
        public T get(int i) {
            return i>=f.length ? o[i - f.length] : f[i];
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return f.length + o.length;
        }

    }.toArray(f);
}
```

I believe the above is equivalent to solutions that uses `System.arraycopy`. However I think this one has its own beauty.

Answer (score 4):

How about :

```
public String[] combineArray (String[] ... strings) {
    List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
        tmpList.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings[i]));
    return tmpList.toArray(new String[tmpList.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common).

```
String[] a = {"a", "b", "c"};
String[] b = {"1", "2", "3"};
String[] c = N.concat(a, b); // c = ["a", "b", "c", "1", "2", "3"]

// N.concat(...) is null-safety.
a = null;
c = N.concat(a, b); // c = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is probably the only generic and type-safe way:

```
public class ArrayConcatenator<T> {
    private final IntFunction<T[]> generator;

    private ArrayConcatenator(IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    public static <T> ArrayConcatenator<T> concat(IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
        return new ArrayConcatenator<>(generator);
    }

    public T[] apply(T[] array1, T[] array2) {
        T[] array = generator.apply(array1.length + array2.length);
        System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array, 0, array1.length);
        System.arraycopy(array2, 0, array, array1.length, array2.length);
        return array;
    }
}
```

And the usage is quite concise:

```
Integer[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
Double[] array2 = { 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 };
Number[] array = concat(Number[]::new).apply(array1, array2);
```

(requires static import)

Invalid array types are rejected:

```
concat(String[]::new).apply(array1, array2); // error
concat(Integer[]::new).apply(array1, array2); // error
```

Answer (score 3):

Using only Javas own API:

```
String[] join(String[]... arrays) {
  // calculate size of target array
  int size = 0;
  for (String[] array : arrays) {
    size += array.length;
  }

  // create list of appropriate size
  java.util.List list = new java.util.ArrayList(size);

  // add arrays
  for (String[] array : arrays) {
    list.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(array));
  }

  // create and return final array
  return list.toArray(new String[size]);
}
```

Now, this code ist not the most efficient, but it relies only on standard java classes and is easy to understand. It works for any number of String[] (even zero arrays).

Comment: Had to downvote this one for all the unnecessary List object creation.

Answer (score 3):

An easy, but inefficient, way to do this (generics not included):

```
ArrayList baseArray = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array1));
baseArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
String concatenated[] = (String []) baseArray.toArray(new String[baseArray.size()]);
```

Answer (score 3):

A type independent variation (UPDATED - thanks to Volley for instantiating T):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] join(T[]...arrays) {

    final List<T> output = new ArrayList<T>();

    for(T[] array : arrays) {
        output.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    }

    return output.toArray((T[])Array.newInstance(
        arrays[0].getClass().getComponentType(), output.size()));
}
```

Comment: I still like Joachim Sauer's solution better.

Comment: I'm still on Java 5 so can't use Arrays.copyOf() as Joachim is doing.

Answer (score 3):

I found I had to deal with the case where the arrays can be null...

```
private double[] concat  (double[]a,double[]b){
    if (a == null) return b;
    if (b == null) return a;
    double[] r = new double[a.length+b.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, r, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, r, a.length, b.length);
    return r;

}
private double[] copyRest (double[]a, int start){
    if (a == null) return null;
    if (start > a.length)return null;
    double[]r = new double[a.length-start];
    System.arraycopy(a,start,r,0,a.length-start); 
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String [] both = new ArrayList<String>(){{addAll(Arrays.asList(first)); addAll(Arrays.asList(second));}}.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Tricky, it compiles only if `first` and `second` are final

Comment: True. I thought it was worth it to add a one-liner without external library.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String[] toArray(String[]... object){
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for (String[] i : object) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(i));
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Every single answer is copying data and creating a new array. This is not strictly necessary and is definitely NOT what you want to do if your arrays are reasonably large. Java creators already knew that array copies are wasteful and that is why they provided us System.arrayCopy() to do those outside Java when we have to.

Instead of copying your data around, consider leaving it in place and draw from it where it lies. Copying data locations just because the programmer would like to organize them is not always sensible.

```
// I have arrayA and arrayB; would like to treat them as concatenated
// but leave my damn bytes where they are!
Object accessElement ( int index ) {
     if ( index < 0 ) throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(...);
     // is reading from the head part?
     if ( index < arrayA.length )
          return arrayA[ index ];
     // is reading from the tail part?
     if ( index < ( arrayA.length + arrayB.length ) )
          return arrayB[ index - arrayA.length ];
     throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(...); // index too large
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to work with ArrayLists in the solution, you can try this:

```
public final String [] f(final String [] first, final String [] second) {
    // Assuming non-null for brevity.
    final ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(first));
    resultList.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(second)));
    return resultList.toArray(new String [resultList.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one based on SilverTab's suggestion, but made to support x number of arguments and not require Java 6. It is also not generic, but I'm sure it could be made generic.

```
private byte[] concat(byte[]... args)
{
    int fulllength = 0;
    for (byte[] arrItem : args)
    {
        fulllength += arrItem.length;
    }
    byte[] retArray = new byte[fulllength];
    int start = 0;
    for (byte[] arrItem : args)
    {
        System.arraycopy(arrItem, 0, retArray, start, arrItem.length);
        start += arrItem.length;
    }
    return retArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Import java.util.*;

String array1[] = {"bla","bla"};
String array2[] = {"bla","bla"};

ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array1));
tempArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(array2));
String array3[] = films.toArray(new String[1]); // size will be overwritten if needed
```

You could replace String by a Type/Class of your liking

Im sure this can be made shorter and better, but it works and im to lazy to sort it out further...

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution with generics would be:

```
/* This for non primitive types */
public static <T> T[] concatenate (T[]... elements) {

    T[] C = null;
    for (T[] element: elements) {
        if (element==null) continue;
        if (C==null) C = (T[]) Array.newInstance(element.getClass().getComponentType(), element.length);
        else C = resizeArray(C, C.length+element.length);

        System.arraycopy(element, 0, C, C.length-element.length, element.length);
    }

    return C;
}

/**
 * as far as i know, primitive types do not accept generics 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types
 * for primitive types we could do something like this:
 * */
public static int[] concatenate (int[]... elements){
    int[] C = null;
    for (int[] element: elements) {
        if (element==null) continue;
        if (C==null) C = new int[element.length];
        else C = resizeArray(C, C.length+element.length);

        System.arraycopy(element, 0, C, C.length-element.length, element.length);
    }
    return C;
}

private static <T> T resizeArray (T array, int newSize) {
    int oldSize =
            java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(array);
    Class elementType =
            array.getClass().getComponentType();
    Object newArray =
            java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                    elementType, newSize);
    int preserveLength = Math.min(oldSize, newSize);
    if (preserveLength > 0)
        System.arraycopy(array, 0,
                newArray, 0, preserveLength);
    return (T) newArray;
}
```

Comment: This seems like useful code and catches both objects and base types. I would however not call a function `resizeArray` because arrays *cannot* be resized in Java. This is why `Arrays.copyOf` does the same thing, but with a different method name.

Comment: Not really, copyOf just makes a copy with the same length, if you read the code carefully, you will realize that the function receives the parameter `newSize` so resizeArray does just that, returns a resized array.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] mergeArrays(int [] a, int [] b) {
    int [] merged = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int i = 0, k = 0, l = a.length;
    int j = a.length > b.length ? a.length : b.length;
    while(i < j) {
        if(k < a.length) {
            merged[k] = a[k];
            k++;
        }
        if((l - a.length) < b.length) {
            merged[l] = b[l - a.length];
            l++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Comment: That's very convoluted, hard to understand, undocumented and - with two if statements in the loop - rather inefficient as well.

Answer (score 1):

Non Java 8 solution:

```
public static int[] combineArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            c[i] = a[i];
        }

        for (int j = 0, k = a.length; j < b.length; j++, k++) {
            c[k] = b[j];
        }

        return c;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 /**
     * With Java Streams
     * @param first First Array
     * @param second Second Array
     * @return Merged Array
     */
    String[] mergeArrayOfStrings(String[] first, String[] second) {
        return Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(first), Arrays.stream(second)).toArray(String[]::new);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested below code and worked ok

Also I'm using library: org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils

```
public void testConcatArrayString(){
    String[] a = null;
    String[] b = null;
    String[] c = null;
    a = new String[] {"1","2","3","4","5"};
    b = new String[] {"A","B","C","D","E"};

    c = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(a, b);
    if(c!=null){
        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++){
            System.out.println("c[" + (i+1) + "] = " + c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] obj = {"hi","there"};
Object[] obj2 ={"im","fine","what abt u"};
Object[] obj3 = new Object[obj.length+obj2.length];

for(int i =0;i<obj3.length;i++)
    obj3[i] = (i<obj.length)?obj[i]:obj2[i-obj.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i could find is as following :

```
List allFiltersList = Arrays.asList(regularFilters);
allFiltersList.addAll(Arrays.asList(preFiltersArray));
Filter[] mergedFilterArray = (Filter[]) allFiltersList.toArray();
```

Comment: Easy yes. But converting to and from a List does not sound very performant.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
 public static Object[] addTwoArray(Object[] objArr1, Object[] objArr2){
    int arr1Length = objArr1!=null && objArr1.length>0?objArr1.length:0;
    int arr2Length = objArr2!=null && objArr2.length>0?objArr2.length:0;
    Object[] resutlentArray = new Object[arr1Length+arr2Length]; 
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<resutlentArray.length;i++){
        if(i+1<=arr1Length){
            resutlentArray[i]=objArr1[i];
        }else{
            resutlentArray[i]=objArr2[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    return resutlentArray;
}
```

U can type cast your array !!!

Comment: `resutlentArray`? `addTwoArray`? Hard to read code and YouTube style comments !!!

Answer (score 0):

This one works only with int but the idea is generic

```
public static int[] junta(int[] v, int[] w) {

int[] junta = new int[v.length + w.length];

for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {            
    junta[i] = v[i];
}

for (int j = v.length; j < junta.length; j++) {
    junta[j] = w[j - v.length];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[] mixArray(String[] a, String[] b)
String[] s1 = a;
String[] s2 = b;
Object[] result;
List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++)
{
    input.add(s1[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++)
{
    input.add(s2[i]);
}
result = input.toArray();
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer for algorithm lovers:

```
public static String[] mergeArrays(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
    int totalSize = array1.length + array2.length; // Get total size
    String[] merged = new String[totalSize]; // Create new array
    // Loop over the total size
    for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) {
        if (i < array1.length) // If the current position is less than the length of the first array, take value from first array
            merged[i] = array1[i]; // Position in first array is the current position

        else // If current position is equal or greater than the first array, take value from second array.
            merged[i] = array2[i - array1.length]; // Position in second array is current position minus length of first array.
    }

    return merged;
```

Usage:

```
String[] array1str = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"}; 
String[] array2str = new String[]{"e", "f", "g", "h", "i"};
String[] listTotalstr = mergeArrays(array1str, array2str);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listTotalstr));
```

Result:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
```

Comment: An if statement per copy is not a brilliant idea as it will have a hefty performance hit.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it's always nice to learn new approaches focused on performance. Any suggestions to improve this?

Comment: Well, yes, `arrayCopy` but I guess that's mentioned in quite a few other examples. Same for two or more `for` loops; it is possible to bring the branching (the if statements) out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method which concatenates multiple arrays:

```
public static <T> T[] concatMultipleArrays(T[]... arrays)
{
   int length = 0;
   for (T[] array : arrays)
   {
      length += array.length;
   }
   T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arrays.getClass().getComponentType(), length) ;

   length = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
   {
      System.arraycopy(arrays[i], 0, result, length, arrays[i].length);
      length += arrays[i].length;
   }

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8

```
public String[] concat(String[] arr1, String[] arr2){
    Stream<String> stream1 = Stream.of(arr1);
    Stream<String> stream2 = Stream.of(arr2);
    Stream<String> stream = Stream.concat(stream1, stream2);
    return Arrays.toString(stream.toArray(String[]::new));
}
```

Comment: This is the same as a previous answer 10 Feb 16.

Comment: @rghome You can link to answers by hitting the share button. Basic, why not remove the answer if there is a clear dupe of an earlier date? If you want you can improve the existing one, if anything is missing there.

Answer (score 0):

*concatenates a series of arrays compact, fast and type-safe with lambda*

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> T[] concat( T[]... arrays ) {
  return( Stream.of( arrays ).reduce( ( arr1, arr2 ) -> {
      T[] rslt = Arrays.copyOf( arr1, arr1.length + arr2.length );
      System.arraycopy( arr2, 0, rslt, arr1.length, arr2.length );
      return( rslt );
    } ).orElse( null ) );
};
```

returns `null` when called without argument

eg. example with 3 arrays:

```
String[] a = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
String[] b = new String[] { "e", "f", "g", "h" };
String[] c = new String[] { "i", "j", "k", "l" };

concat( a, b, c );  // [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l]
```

*"…probably the only generic and type-safe way"* – adapted:

```
Number[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
Number[] array2 = { 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 };
Number[] array = concat( array1, array2 );  // [1, 2, 3, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, you can use `System.arraycopy` too:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.System.arraycopy;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
class Playground {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T>T[] combineArrays(T[] a1, T[] a2) {
        T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(a1.getClass().getComponentType(), a1.length+a2.length);
        arraycopy(a1,0,result,0,a1.length);
        arraycopy(a2,0,result,a1.length,a2.length);
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        String monthsString = "JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC";
        String[] months = monthsString.split("(?<=\\G.{3})");
        String daysString = "SUNMONTUEWEDTHUFRISAT";
        String[] days = daysString.split("(?<=\\G.{3})");
        for (String m : months) {
            out.println(m);
        }
        out.println("===");
         for (String d : days) {
            out.println(d);
        }
        out.println("===");
        String[] results = combineArrays(months, days);
        for (String r : results) {
            out.println(r);
        }
        out.println("===");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use next method to concatenate any number of arrays of the same type using java 8:

```
public static <G> G[] concatenate(IntFunction<G[]> generator, G[] ... arrays) {
    int len = arrays.length;
    if (len == 0) {
        return generator.apply(0);
    } else if (len == 1) {
        return arrays[0];
    }
    int pos = 0;
    Stream<G> result = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(arrays[pos]), Arrays.stream(arrays[++pos]));
    while (pos < len - 1) {
        result = Stream.concat(result, Arrays.stream(arrays[++pos]));
    }
    return result.toArray(generator);
}
```

usage:

```
 concatenate(String[]::new, new String[]{"one"}, new String[]{"two"}, new String[]{"three"})
```

or

```
 concatenate(Integer[]::new, new Integer[]{1}, new Integer[]{2}, new Integer[]{3})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered this question, sorry very late, and saw a lot of answers that were too far away,
using certain libraries, using the feature of converting data from an array to a stream and back to an array and so on. But,
we can just use a simple loop and the problem is done

```java
public String[] concat(String[] firstArr,String[] secondArr){
        //if both is empty just return
        if(firstArr.length==0 && secondArr.length==0)return new String[0];

        String[] res = new String[firstArr.length+secondArr.length];
        int idxFromFirst=0;

        //loop over firstArr, idxFromFirst will be used as starting offset for secondArr
        for(int i=0;i<firstArr.length;i++){
            res[i] = firstArr[i];
            idxFromFirst++;
        }

        //loop over secondArr, with starting offset idxFromFirst (the offset track from first array)
        for(int i=0;i<secondArr.length;i++){
            res[idxFromFirst+i]=secondArr[i];
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Thats it all, right? he didnt say he care about the order or anything.
This should be the easiest way of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple method. You don't want to waste your time to research complex java functions or libraries. But the return type should be String.

```
String[] f(String[] first, String[] second) {

    // Variable declaration part
    int len1 = first.length;
    int len2 = second.length;
    int lenNew = len1 + len2;
    String[] both = new String[len1+len2];

    // For loop to fill the array "both"
    for (int i=0 ; i<lenNew ; i++){
        if (i<len1) {
            both[i] = first[i];
        } else {
            both[i] = second[i-len1];
        }
    }

    return both;

}
```

So simple...

Comment: This is good enough for my Leetcode practice :) God I hate java!

Answer (score 0):

Using Java Collections

Well, Java doesn't provide a helper method to concatenate arrays. However, since Java 5, the Collections utility class has introduced an addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T… elements) method.

We can create a List object, then call this method twice to add the two arrays to the list. Finally, we convert the resulting List back to an array:

```
static <T> T[] concatWithCollection(T[] array1, T[] array2) {
    List<T> resultList = new ArrayList<>(array1.length + array2.length);
    Collections.addAll(resultList, array1);
    Collections.addAll(resultList, array2);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    //the type cast is safe as the array1 has the type T[]
    T[] resultArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(array1.getClass().getComponentType(), 0);
    return resultList.toArray(resultArray);
}
```

Test

```
@Test
public void givenTwoStringArrays_whenConcatWithList_thenGetExpectedResult() {
    String[] result = ArrayConcatUtil.concatWithCollection(strArray1, strArray2);
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expectedStringArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many generic answers with signatures such as public static  T[] concat(T[] a, T[] b) {} but these only work on Object arrays, not on primitive arrays, as far as I can work out. The code below works both on Object and primitive arrays, making it more generic...

```
public static <T> T concat(T a, T b) {
        //Handles both arrays of Objects and primitives! E.g., int[] out = concat(new int[]{6,7,8}, new int[]{9,10});
        //You get a compile error if argument(s) not same type as output. (int[] in example above)
        //You get a runtime error if output type is not an array, i.e., when you do something like: int out = concat(6,7);
        if (a == null && b == null) return null;
        if (a == null) return b;
        if (b == null) return a;
        final int aLen = Array.getLength(a);
        final int bLen = Array.getLength(b);
        if (aLen == 0) return b;
        if (bLen == 0) return a;
        //From here on we really need to concatenate!

        Class componentType = a.getClass().getComponentType();
        final T result = (T)Array.newInstance(componentType, aLen + bLen);
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, aLen);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, aLen, bLen);
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] out1 = concat(new String[]{"aap", "monkey"}, new String[]{"rat"});
        int[] out2 = concat(new int[]{6,7,8}, new int[]{9,10});
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In Haskell you can do something like that `[a, b, c] ++ [d, e]` to get `[a, b, c, d, e]`. These are Haskell lists concatenated but that'd very nice to see a similar operator in Java for arrays. Don't you think so ? That's elegant, simple, generic and it's not that difficult to implement.

If you want to, I suggest you to have a look at Alexander Hristov's work in his [Hacking the OpenJDK compiler](http://www.ahristov.com/tutoriales/java-compiler/duplicating-lexer.html). He explains how to modify javac source to create a new operator. His example consists in defining a '**' operator where `i ** j = Math.pow(i, j)`. One could take that example to implement an operator that concatenates two arrays of same type.

Once you do that, you are bound to your customized javac to compile your code but the generated bytecode will be understood by any JVM. 
Of course, you can implement your own array concatenatation method at your source level, there are many examples on how to do it in the other answers !

There are so many useful operators that could be added, this one would be one of them.

Comment: WOW nice! why not change the compiler to realize a java syntax problem. :) bold move!

Answer (score -1):

Look at this elegant solution (if you need other type than char, change it):

```
private static void concatArrays(char[] destination, char[]... sources) {
    int currPos = 0;
    for (char[] source : sources) {
        int length = source.length;
        System.arraycopy(source, 0, destination, currPos, length);
        currPos += length;
    }
}
```

You can concatenate a every count of arrays.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As this question is quite old, and System.arraycopy was thoroughly discussed already, it is best to avoid resurrecting old threads unless the response contributes something significant to the thread.

Comment: This is not concatenation but copying. The destination must already have enough space to accommodate all the sources or the above code will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score -1):

Should do the trick. This is assuming String[] first and String[] second

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(first));
myList.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(second)));
String[] both = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
```

Comment: `myList.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(second)));` can be simplified to `myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(second))`

Answer (score -1):

```
    void f(String[] first, String[] second) {
    String[] both = new String[first.length+second.length];
    for(int i=0;i<first.length;i++)
        both[i] = first[i];
    for(int i=0;i<second.length;i++)
        both[first.length + i] = second[i];
}
```

This one works without knowledge of any other classes/libraries etc.
It works for any data type. Just replace `String` with anything like `int`,`double` or `char`.
It works quite efficiently.

Comment: Waste of CPU & Memory. See the answer from @Douglas-Held

Answer (score -2):

Here is what worked for me:

```
String[] data=null;
String[] data2=null;
ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<2;i++) {
   data2 = input.readLine().split(",");
   data1.addAll(Arrays.asList(data2));
   data= data1.toArray(new String[data1.size()]);
   }
```