# How do I concatenate static string arrays

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

I have SET1 declared as a static String[] and I would like to declare SET2 as SET1 + few other parameters. Is it possible to declare SET2 statically similar (i.e. private static String[]) to SET1 but using the above definition, if not how to do this?

```
private static final String[] SET1 = { "1", "2", "3" };

SET2 = SET1 + { "4", "5", "6" };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Commons Util](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) ArrayUtils.add:

```
static String[] SET2 = ArrayUtils.add(SET1, {"4", "5", "6" });
```

Comment: I guess we need to use Object[] and use addAll instead and casting it back to String[]

Comment: I hope it doesn't clone when there are 2 sets of finite arguments. ArrayUtils.addAll(["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]) = ["a", "b", "c", "1", "2", "3"]. Cloning seems to be redundant here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe lists are easier in this case since arrays are fixed in length (by nature). You could do something like this if you want to instantiate it statically.

```
private static final List<String> SET1 = new ArrayList<String>();
private static final List<String> SET2 = new ArrayList<String>();
static {
    SET1.add("1");
    SET1.add("2");
    SET2.addAll(SET1);
    SET2.add("3");
}
```

Or use some kind of Collection utility library.

Answer (score 0):

It's a big ugly:

```
private static final String[] SET1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
private static final String[] SET2 = concat(
    String.class, SET1, new String[]{"4", "5", "6"});

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T> T[] concat(Class<T> clazz, T[] A, T[] B) {
    T[] C= (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, A.length+B.length);
    System.arraycopy(A, 0, C, 0, A.length);
    System.arraycopy(B, 0, C, A.length, B.length);
    return C;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String[] SET1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
private static final String[] SET2;

static
{
    List<String> set2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(SET1));
    set2.addAll(Arrays.asList("3", "4", "5"));
    SET2 = set2.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```