# How to concatenate string arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm wondering how I can concatenate 4 string arrays in Java.

There is a question about this already.
[How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

But I tried to replicate it but it does not work for me.

This is what my code looks like:

Calling the method:

```
concatAll(jobs1, jobs2, jobs3, jobs4);
```

The method itself:

```
public String[] concatAll(String[] jobsA, String[] jobsB, String[] jobsC, String[] jobsD) {
    int totalLength = jobsA.length;
    for (String[] array : jobsD) {
        totalLength += array.length;
    }

    String[] result = Arrays.copyOf(jobsA, totalLength);

    int offset = jobsA.length;

    for (String[] array : jobsD) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, offset, array.length);
        offset += array.length;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm somewhat confused here. What is a sample input, and a sample output?

Comment: How did this not get closed? [Double Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750500/how-do-i-concatenate-static-string-arrays)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Putting aside things like checking if an array is `null`, you can create a general method for it and use it in your specific case, like this:

```
    public String[] concatAll(String[] jobsA, String[] jobsB, String[] jobsC, String[] jobsD) 
    {
        return generalConcatAll (jobsA, jobsB, jobsC, jobsD);
    }

    public String[] generalConcatAll(String[]... jobs) {
        int len = 0;
        for (final String[] job : jobs) {
            len += job.length;
        }

        final String[] result = new String[len];

        int currentPos = 0;
        for (final String[] job : jobs) {
            System.arraycopy(job, 0, result, currentPos, job.length);
            currentPos += job.length;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Still a little confused though... Do I then call generalConcatAll 4 times and pass in each jobs array?

Comment: Or do I call it once and run the for loops 4 times once for each of the jobs arrays?

Comment: No. The body of `concatAll` method gives you the anwer - you pass each job array as a seperate argument.

Comment: @TríonaLounds You might want to read about [Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit more concise, and handles all `null` cases correctly using  Apache Commons Lang library. [`ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)

```
public String[] generalConcatAll(String[]...arrays) {

    String[] result = null;

    for(String[] array : arrays) {
         result = ArrayUtils.addAll(result, array);
    }

    return result;

}
```