# Use of ellipsis(...) in Java?

Tags: java, oop, object, syntax

I was looking through some code and saw the following notation. I'm somewhat unsure what the three dots mean and what you call them.

```
void doAction(Object...o);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It means that this method can receive more than one Object as a parameter. To better understating check the following example from [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/04/19/varargs.html):

> The ellipsis (...) identifies a variable number of arguments, and is
>   demonstrated in the following summation method.

```
static int sum (int ... numbers)
{
   int total = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        total += numbers [i];
   return total;
}
```

> Call the summation method with as many comma-delimited integer
>   arguments as you desire -- within the JVM's limits. Some examples: sum
>   (10, 20) and sum (18, 20, 305, 4).

This is very useful since it permits your method to became more abstract. Check also this nice [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435714/how-to-concatenate-string-arrays-in-java) from SO, were the user takes advantage of the ... notation to make a method to concatenate string arrays in Java.

Another example from  [Variable argument method in Java 5](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/varargs-in-java-variable-argument-method-in-java-5/)

```
public static void test(int some, String... args) {
        System.out.print("\n" + some);
        for(String arg: args) {
            System.out.print(", " + arg);
        }
    }
```

As mention in the comment section:

> Also note that if the function passes other parameters of different
>   types than varargs parameter, the vararg parameter should be the last
>   parameter in the function declaration **public void test (Typev ... v ,
>   Type1 a, Type2 b)** or **public void test(Type1 a, Typev ... v
>   recipientJids, Type2 b)** - is **illegal**. ONLY **public void test(Type1 a,
>   Type2 b, Typev ... v)**

Comment: Hi dreamcrash! I was just thinking that an example would be cool to add to your post, as well as what Java version this applies to. I'm stuck on Java 6 due to being on Google's App Engine, but I know the newer Java versions have some pretty cool new features. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Also note that if the function passes other parameters of different types than varargs parameter, the vararg parameter should be the **last**  parameter in the function declaration. i.e. `public void test ( Typev ... v , Type1 a,  Type2 b)`   or   `public void test(Type1 a, Typev ... v recipientJids,  Type2 b)`  - is   **illegal**.   **ONLY**   `public void test(Type1 a, Type2 b, Typev ... v)` - is **legal**.

Comment: Yep you are right I Will add this information to my post as soon as possible, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's called VarArgs http://www.javadb.com/using-varargs-in-java. In this case, it means you can put multiple instances of Object as a parameter to doAction() as many as you wants :

```
doAction(new Object(), new Object(), new Object());
```