# What is the syntax when calling an array method?

Tags: java

I have no problem calling methods that require String or int inputs. For example:

```
return stringMethod("Hello World");
return intMethod(1,2,3);
```

but I'm having an issue with the syntax when calling a method which requires array of ints for the input.  The syntax I use to call the method countEvens in the code below is not working.

```
public class _01_countEvens{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        return countEvens({2,4,6,7});
        }

    }
    public int countEvens(int[] nums){
        int result = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < nums.length; x++){
            if(nums[x] % 2 == 0) result++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you can't return an `int` from `main()`, because it is declared as a `void` method.

Comment: I'm actually using Arrays.toString() to output, i was just trying to simplify. But thanks, you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This syntax

```
{2,4,6,7}
```

is the array creation syntax and can only be used in array creation expressions

```
new int[]{2,4,6,7}
```

Read the official Java tutorial on Arrays [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: thanks.  I added an image to my original post of the actual problem I'm working on at codingbat.com  The method public int countEvens(int[] nums) works and the tests he runs are in the format countEvens({2, 1, 2, 3, 4}) is being used to call it.  This is why I'm lost.  When I call it that way in a Eclipse or Netbeans, it doesn't work.

Comment: @StuartKuredjian That's just notation for the website, it's invalid Java syntax.

Comment: @StuartKuredjian See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665930/use-of-ellipsis-in-java) about the ellipsis.

Answer (score 6):

Either change your method header to:

```
public int countEvents(int... nums)
```

And remove the `{` and `}` in the call to countEvents,

Or pass: `new int[]{2, 4, 6, 7}` as an argument.

Comment: I tried using int... instead of int[] and it doesn't work.  But doesn't it need to be [] to specify it as an array?  And what does ... mean?

Comment: ok calling it with countEvens(new int[]{2, 4, 6, 7}); worked. Thanks. Though I'd still like to know who to make your first suggestion work.  Not sure what int... means.

Comment: @StuartKuredjian Rather than trying to explain it myself, a good explanation can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2367412/1255746).

Answer (score 0):

Array:

```
int[] a = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

Double Array:

```
int[][] a2 = {
        {0,1,2}
        {3,4,5}
};
```

From there on, just add arrays inside each array. You shouldn't have to make that many dimensions though.