# Copy several byte arrays to one big byte array

Tags: java, arrays

I have one big `byte[]` array and lot of small `byte` arrays ( length of big array is sum of lengths small arrays). Is there maybe some quick method to copy one array to another from starting position to ending, not to use for loop for every byte manually ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use a [`ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

```
ByteBuffer target = ByteBuffer.wrap(bigByteArray);
target.put(small1);
target.put(small2);
...;
```

Comment: Pretty sure this'd use a similar code internally as was suggested by other answers. Upvoted, it's usually better to use a built-in method than re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Downvoted. This doesn't account for the case where the final length of the big array is unknown at the time the first partial arrays are delivered.

Comment: @Zom-B the question starts of with "I have one big byte array" so it looked like the size of the array is alread known beforehand.

Comment: Use `ByteBuffer.allocate(size)`, if you need array of given `size`, but don't have it yet. Then, invoke `target.getArray()` after all `target.put()` invocations.

Answer (score 25):

Use [`System.arraycopy()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)).

You could also apply the solution from [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java/784842#784842). Note that for primitive types such as `byte` you'll have to produce separate versions (one for each primitive type), as generics don't work there.

Comment: +1 for your previous answer. It will also work for primitive types, if you let it accept to Object parameters instead of two T[]s. But that does of course mean there's no compile-time checking.

Comment: @Sean: unfortunately there's no `Arrays.copyOf()` that takes an `Object`.

Comment: argh, confused that with `System.arrayCopy()`

Comment: seems weird this is a `System` method!

Answer (score 13):

Or you could use a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) (Although it creates the resulting array for you, rather than copying into an existing array as you asked).

```
public byte[] concatenateByteArrays(List<byte[]> blocks) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (byte[] b : blocks) {
        os.write(b, 0, b.length);
    }
    return os.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: Just watch this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/5d930ca/luni/src/main/java/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java

Your code is very ineffective.

Answer (score 6):

### Sample Implementation

```
public static void copySmallArraysToBigArray(final byte[][] smallArrays,
    final byte[] bigArray){
    int currentOffset = 0;
    for(final byte[] currentArray : smallArrays){
        System.arraycopy(
            currentArray, 0,
            bigArray, currentOffset,
            currentArray.length
        );
        currentOffset += currentArray.length;
    }
}
```

### Test Code

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    final byte[][] smallArrays =
        {
           "The"    .getBytes(),
           " Quick" .getBytes(),
           " Brown" .getBytes(),
           " Fox"   .getBytes()
        };
    final byte[] bigArray = "The Small Mauve Cat".getBytes();
    copySmallArraysToBigArray(smallArrays, bigArray);
    System.out.println(new String(bigArray));
}
```

**Output:**

> The Quick Brown Fox

Comment: I'd remove the check and the throwing of the exception, because `System.arraycopy()` already throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the indices are out of bounds (and that exception gives a bit more information as well).

Comment: @sean: please use getBytes(Charset.forName("ASCII")) or similar in next samples (as getBytes() depends on the runtime system for the character encoding)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution which also uses [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(List<byte[]> bytesList)
{
    int size = 0;

    for (byte[] bytes : bytesList)
    {
        size += bytes.length;
    }

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);

    for (byte[] bytes : bytesList)
    {
        byteBuffer.put(bytes);
    }

    return byteBuffer.array();
}
```