# Java custom arrayMerge function

Tags: java, arrays, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 int arrays using this custom function I found on Google:

```
public static <T> T[] arrayMerge(T[]... arrays)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (T[] array : arrays) count += array.length;

    T[] mergedArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(arrays[0][0].getClass(),count);
    int start = 0;
    for (T[] array : arrays) {
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, mergedArray, start, array.length);
        start += array.length;
    }
    return (T[]) mergedArray;
}
```

but I'm fail to understand what parameters this function takes. I was hoping it would work like arrayMerge(int[], int[]), but Eclipse tells me it doesn't take these arguments. 
I can't Google a capital T to find an answer.

You can answer in a form or reading material, but an example of using this function to merge 2 int arrays would be nice (does it eliminate duplicates, if not, how can I also achieve that?).

Comment: You can avoid the rather ugly (and dangerous) `arrays[0][0]` by using `Arrays.copyOf()` as shown in [a previous answer from me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java/784842#784842). The problem with `arrays[0][0]` is two-fold: the first array *might* be empty, in which case you'd get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and the first element might not be of the type of the array (e.g. it could be an `Integer` in an `Object[]`) or it could even be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The method takes any number of arrays, all having the same type:

```
String[] array1 = ... ;
String[] array2 = ... ;
String[] array3 = ... ;
String[] mergedArray = ArrayHelper.arrayMerge(array1, array2, array3);
```

However, due the way generics work in Java, you cannot pass an array of a primitive type (such as `int[]`).

Comment: Then how come I'm getting: The method arrayMerge(T[]...) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int[])

Comment: Because generics do not work with primitive types. Even when used as array elements. T can only stand in for types, which can be assigned to Object without conversions (like boxing)

Comment: @Dirk: those are usually called "reference types".

Comment: @joachim - I tried to avoid the lingo (and utterly failed - “generics“, “boxing“), but thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @Dirk: I thought so, actually my comment was directed at user781655 as well. Just wanted to get the term out there.

Comment: @user781655 - If you want to use this function to merge 2 (or more) integer arrays, you can use the wrapper class `Integer` instead of the primitive type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have post here is for any type of array not only `int` and for more than 2 arrays to merge. (unlimited)
`T` stand for a generic Type. see [Generics in Java](http://%20download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

You can use only the `System.arraycopy(Object src,  int  srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)`

- `src` the source array.
- `srcPos` starting position in the source array.
- `dest` the destination array.
- `destPos` starting position in the destination data.
- `length` the number of array elements to be copied.

First make an array which has the length of both arrays.

```
public merge(int[] x, int[] y) {

    int[] merged = new int[x.length + y.length]
```

Than copy with `System.arraycopy` the first array `x` into `merged` at `0`.
And copy with `System.arraycopy` the 2nd array `y` into `merged` at `x.length`

**But** it doesn't eliminate duplicates.

For no duplicates you can use a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). But we have to work with `Integer` not `int`.

 So we have to convert to `Integer` an back to `int`. like:

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for( int i : x ) {
    set.add( Integer.valueOf( i ) );
}
for( int i : y ) {
    set.add( Integer.valueOf( i ) );
}
int[] merged = new int[set.size()];
int i = 0;
for( Integer value : set ) {
    merged[i++] = value.intValue();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That syntax is called [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) - it means it will accept any number of parameters of that type. Removing the generics to simply the explanation, a method defined as this:

```
public static void someMethod(int... numbers) {
    // some code
}
```

can be called like this:

```
someMethod(5); // The "numbers" parameter will be an int array size 1: [5]
someMethod(1,2,3); // The "numbers" parameter will be an int array size 3: [1, 2, 3]
someMethod(); // The "numbers" parameter will be an int array size 0: []
```

It's like a shorthand for this:

```
someMethod(new int[] {1, 2, 3});
```

but less ugly.

In your example, the array is a typed generic array - you don't know what the element type is until it's called.