# Array Confusion with Doubles/doubles

Tags: java, arrays

I have two Arrays that are initialized as such:

```
    public static double[] arrayweight= new double[100];
    public static double[] arraypulse= new double[100];
```

They are filled with data e.g. 23.0,25.8....etc.

I need to combine the two Arrays into one array of `double[]`

I have chosen to use the following approach which does not work.   Any ideas?

```
     ArrayList <Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();

// The following methods do not work ;(     
     al.add((double[]) Global.arrayweight);
     al.add(new Double(Global.arraypulse));
```

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Comment: `Arrayweight` and `Arraypulse` should be named `arrayWeight` `arrayPulse`. Look up Java naming conventions.

Comment: The types (and cardinalities) do not match at all. You are trying to add a whole array as an element of the list that is not a list of arrays, and then trying to convert an array to a single Double object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Nammari's answer best, but *just in case you are not using Commons Lang* and want to stick with pure Java:

```
double[] result = Arrays.copyOf(Arrayweight, Arrayweight.length + Arraypulse.length);
System.arrayCopy(Arraypulse, 0, result, Arrayweight.length, Arraypulse.length);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it using [System.arraycopy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

```
double[] cArray= new double[Arrayweight.length + Arraypulse.length];
System.arraycopy(Arrayweight, 0, cArray, 0, Arrayweight.length);
System.arraycopy(Arraypulse, 0, cArray, Arrayweight.length, Arraypulse.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the easy way:

```
double[] arr = new double[Arrayweight.length + Arraypulse.length];
int counter = 0;
for(double d1 : Arrayweight) arr[counter++] = d1;
for(double d2 : Arraypulse)  arr[counter++] = d2;
```

or (if they have same length):

```
int length = Arrayweight.length + Arraypulse.length;
double[] arr = new double[length];
for(int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Arrayweight[i];
    arr[i + length / 2] = Arraypulse[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find [TDoubleArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TDoubleArrayList.html) useful. This is a wrapper for double[].

```
TDoubleArrayList al = new TDoubleArrayList();
al.add(Arrayweight);
al.add(Arraypulse);
```

However your naming suggest you are using arrays when objects might be a better approach.

```
class MyData {
    double weight, pulse;
}

List<MyData> al = new ArrayList<MyData>();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    MyData md = new MyData();
    md.weight = ...
    md.pulse = ...
    al.add(md);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] both = (double[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(Arrayweight, Arraypulse);
```

Answer (score -1):

The add method takes individual values, not arrays. You can combine List's [addAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) and Arrays' [asList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method (if you want to stick with an ArrayList):

```
al.addAll(Arrays.asList(Global.Arrayweight));
al.addAll(Arrays.asList(Global.Arraypulse));
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` doesn't work for primitive arrays, at least not in the way you intend it to.