# java from for loop to recursion in finding combination

Tags: java, loops, recursion, for-loop

how can i change this for loop to recursive in the event that if groupSize=3, n=6 will print 
123
124
125
126
134
135
136
145
146
156
234
235
236
245
246
345
346
356
456

```
public static void printCombinations(int groupSize, int n){

    if (groupSize <=n && groupSize>0 && n>0){

            for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
                for (int j=1; j<=i-1; j++){
                    for (int k=1; k<=j-1; k++){
                        int first = k;
                        int second = j;
                        int third = i;
                        if (i!=j && i!=k && j!=k){
                            System.out.println(first +" " + second +" "+ third);
                            }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. n can't be less than zero of groupSize is greater than 0 and less than n. 2. Your second for loop won't run because the first value of i is 1, so when j is 1, it's going to be greater than 1-1, which is 0.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Walkerneo: Seems like a reasonable use of recursion to me.

Comment: @MarkByers, yeah, I thought he was doing something else initially

Comment: OK, so you're trying to print all numbers with the amount of digits in groupSize using the numbers 1 through n such that the the digit in the hundred's place is less than the digit in the tens is less than the digit in the ones?

Comment: @Joh: Of course it's homework, why even ask?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Don't like to retag to homework without confirmation since that can affect how answers are given

Comment: @Joh: Don't retag it. Please read the meta discussions on this as this has been discussed over and over and the large majority strongly advise against re-tagging with meta tags like homework. For instance, check this link: [definitive-answer-regarding-retagging-homework-questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79475/definitive-answer-regarding-retagging-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Probably going to be rough around the edges; I'm just learning Java.

```
class comboMaker {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] test1 = startCombo(3,6);
        prnt(test1);
    }
    private static String[] startCombo(int len,int digits){
        return combos(len,digits,"",0);
    }
    private static String[] combos(int len,int digits,String cur,int lastdig){
        if (len>digits){
            return null;
        }
        if (cur.length()==len){
            return new String[]{cur};           
        }
        String tmp = cur;
        String[] rtn = {};
        for(int i = lastdig+1;i<=digits;i++){
            tmp=cur+Integer.toString(i);
            rtn=concat(rtn,combos(len,digits,tmp,i));   
        }
        return rtn;

    }
    private static String[] concat(String[] A, String[] B) {
           String[] C= new String[A.length+B.length];
           System.arraycopy(A, 0, C, 0, A.length);
           System.arraycopy(B, 0, C, A.length, B.length);
           return C;
    }

    private static void prnt(String[] str){
        if(str==null){
            System.out.println("Invalid string array");
            return;
        }
        for(int i =0;i<str.length;i++ ){
            System.out.println(str[i]);
        }   
    }   
}
```

I included a method to concatenate arrays that I found here: [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Also a method to print your string array generated with the combo maker.

Comment: considering this was probably homework, it would have probably been better not to have given such a complete / explicit answer.

Comment: Maybe it's not homework. Maybe this will help him when he otherwise would have failed the class. I honestly have no clue, but I'm trying to learn Python and Java, so I just wanted the experience.

Comment: Thank everyone for the example given, I am in the process of learning java and this is about to learn recursion, the code above is written in not a good way though if I change the groupSize to 4, it will not work. So, I plant to write it in recursion way. =)

Comment: Output if using comboStart(4,6): `1234
1235
1236
1245
1246
1256
1345
1346
1356
1456
2345
2346
2356
2456
3456
`

The length of the numbers generated can't be more than the number of digits given, or else there aren't enough digits for each value to be greater than the last.

Comment: sorry Walkerneo, the code i mentioned is the code i wrote, your code is working fine.

Comment: user963501: If you found this answer to be helpful, you should give @Walkerneo credit

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that will produce the suffix to a particular value with x digits and return a list of all possible suffixes. Might be something like:

```
List<String> generateSuffixes(int prefix, int suffixSize, int maxDigitValue);
```

The method would iterate from `prefix + 1` to `maxDigitValue`. It would then call itself with the iterate value and `suffixSize - 1`. It would append the iterate to each suffix generated to create the list to return.