# Cryptography : using Password Based Encryption (PBE)

Tags: java, cryptography

I want to use PBE to encrypt my data. So far, I have written the following code :

```
    moteurCryptage = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");

        PBEKeySpec spécifClé=new PBEKeySpec(mdp.toCharArray());
        SecretKeyFactory usineàClefs=SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey clé=null;
        try {
            clé = usineàClefs.generateSecret(spécifClé);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DiskUtilView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    moteurCryptage.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,clé);
        byte[] paramètresEncodage;
        try {
            paramètresEncodage=moteurCryptage.getParameters().getEncoded();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            paramètresEncodage=null;
        }

    destination=moteurCryptage.update(source1.getBytes());
    destination=moteurCryptage.doFinal(source2.getBytes());

    moteurCryptage.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,clé,paramètresEncodage);

    source=new String(moteurCryptage.doFinal(destination));
```

Encryption seems to work (I don't get any error, neither during compilation nor execution) but the initialisation of the `Cipher` object for decryption doesn't accept the `javax.crypto.SecretKey` class (compilation error). It instead asks for a `java.security.key`.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: Uff, the french characters were hard to eliminate. Also, the variable names would be much more readable if in English :). And there were variables that were of unknown type to us. Please, next time, try to make it as compilable as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
moteurCryptage.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, cle, parametresEncodage);
```

which should be

```
moteurCryptage.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, cle, moteurCryptage.getParameters());
```

Also, as you pointed out, it then doesn't work for some strings (works only for those really short). The problem is that when you call `update()`, it saves some data into the resulting `byte[]`. When you call `doFinal()` on the same variable, it overwrites the data and they are lost forever. The `doFinal()` method doesn't do all the encrypting again, it only does the remaining part!

That means, that you

- have to concatenate the source strings before you process them
- or you have to preserve `destination` after `update()`, make `destination2` for `doFinal()` and then both decrypt the same way - `update()` `destination` and `doFinal()` `destination2`
- or you can make `destination` and `destination2`, concatenate them ([here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java), e.g.) into a single `completeDestination` array and do decrypting `doFinal()` on that.

If you would like to see the code for all the above, just say a word.

Comment: Well, it almost work fine. The compilation error has disappeared, encryption realized with the call of "doFinal" is correctly decrypted but a "double" encryption with a call to "update" followed by a call to "doFinal" leads to an unexpected result : if the first string is "First  string" and the second string is "Second String", the decrypted result I obtain is "��/�q�L�nd string". :(

Comment: OH! I'm going to edit my answer in 5 minutes, I have the solution.

Comment: I confirm that encrypting only one string at a time works. So, it is a solution to my problem. Nevertheles, it sounds strange : if I encrypt with "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", the decrypted string contains both strings, one after the other. It seems that "update" and "doFinal" work differently depending on the algorithm used.

Comment: I didn't test this, but I'd _guess_ that the `update()` on RSA returned `null` (please verify?), then the `doFinal()` encrypted the whole message. If the cipher is a block cipher, then `update()` encrypts only that much of the input that makes some blocks, and stores the rest in internal buffer for `doFinal()` or another `update`s. Enlarging the input sufficiently should conclude in the same behaviour we saw here.