# Migrate Oracle authentication to table

Tags: java, oracle, authentication, oracle11g

I have a web application based on Java/Spring that uses Oracle 11g. Currently, the users authenticate via username/password directly against the system table `SYS.USER$` on login.

This has to change, so we created a (regular) new table to store all the user data there. We inserted all existing passwords to the newly created table. However, the passwords seem to be encrypted/hashed in a way that's described by [this site](http://www.red-database-security.com/whitepaper/oracle_passwords.html)

One example: Once the user enters `XXXXX`, the database stores `07E4898C06DEF253`.

I want to perform the authentication with the old passwords stored in the new (regular) table. My problem is that I don't know how to verify the existing passwords since I don't know exactly how they have been hashed/encrypted.

I played around with [ora_hash](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/functions097.htm) and [dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESDecrypt](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_obtool.htm), but none of these gave me a correct result. I know the correct password for my user and I can see Oracle's generated value for this one, but I can't reproduce the way Oracle generally "handles" the password data.

Is there any way to solve this problem without resetting all passwords?

Comment: If you know all the clear-text passwords, why don't you use your own salting+hashing procedure, and replace the old hashed passwords by the new hashed ones?

Comment: No, I don't know all the passwords, just the one for my (admin) user. I'll modify the original question to make that more clear.

Comment: Ah, OK. The linked page says that Oracle11g stores SHA1(password || salt) in a column. It doesn't know what the salt is or where it's stored though. If you can find it, implementing this same algorithm should be very easy. See http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001097.htm for details.

Comment: Thanks for the link, tried that already. Unfortunately I don't have the rights to access SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO. Also, I read on another page that Oracle is using a different salt every time. Actually I don't really need to decode the password, I just want to compare the entered password to the stored one, so there must be some Oracle functionality enabling me to to that...

Comment: SHA1 is a standard algorithm, available in every language on earth. You could hash the password+salt in Java, and compare the result with what is stored in the database. SHA-1 is a one-way function, so reverting the clear-text password from the hash is impossible. The salt seems to be stored in the column, after SHA1(password + salt).

Comment: The example you gave ("07E4898C06DEF253") looks like the value in `password` column, don't you need the value in `spare4` column ? you are using the 11g. Check if `sec_case_sensitive_logon=true`

Comment: Oracle does use an different salt each time but that's stored in `user$` as well so you just need to put this value in your own users table. It seems like the simplest solution would be to get access to `dbms_crypto`. What's stopping you from doing so? If it's a DBA forbidding you access they should also have a reason for doing so.

Comment: Yes, you are right - this is the value in PASSWORD. In SPARE4, I have a SHA-1 encoded value. So I have both and it doesn't really matter which one I use for the validation. Currently I'm fiddling around with the SHA-1 encoding since this looks like the best way to go, but I'm not done yet...

Comment: By the way this is the resource that mentioned that the SHA-1 salt by oracle is random:

[http://marcel.vandewaters.nl/oracle/security/password-hashes](http://marcel.vandewaters.nl/oracle/security/password-hashes)

Comment: @Ben: Where is the salt stored in `user$` ?

Comment: The article linked to by JB Nizet has it, `substr(spare4,43,20)` from `user$`

Comment: I did a Java implementation, but it still gives me a wrong result. Maybe you can have a look:

[http://ideone.com/DBCGU](http://ideone.com/DBCGU)

The SHA-1 encoded result is there, password is "ZK3002".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the Java implementation you linked to in a comment, which is close but isn't quite using the salt properly:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Formatter;

class Main{

    public static String calculateHash(String password) throws Exception{
        MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

        String encodedPassword = "S:71752CE0530476A8B2E0DD218AE59CB71B211D7E1DB70EE23BFB23BDFD48";

        // Convert password to bytes
        byte[] bPassword = password.getBytes("UTF-8");

        // Get salt from encoded password
        String salt = encodedPassword.substring(42, 62);
        System.out.println("Salt is " + salt);

        // Convert salt from hex back to bytes
        // based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/266304
        int len = salt.length();
        byte[] bSalt = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            bSalt[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(salt.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(salt.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }

        // Add converted salt to password bytes
        // based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/80503/266304
        byte[] bData = new byte[bPassword.length + bSalt.length];
        System.arraycopy(bPassword, 0, bData, 0, bPassword.length);
        System.arraycopy(bSalt, 0, bData, bPassword.length, bSalt.length);

        // Hash the final byte array
        crypt.update(bData);
        byte bHash[] = crypt.digest();

        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (byte b : bHash)
        {
            formatter.format("%02x", b);
        }

        System.out.println("Expected      " + encodedPassword.substring(2,42));

        return formatter.toString().toUpperCase();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The result is " + calculateHash("ZK3002"));
    }
}
```

Which gives output:

```
Salt is 1DB70EE23BFB23BDFD48
Expected      71752CE0530476A8B2E0DD218AE59CB71B211D7E
The result is 71752CE0530476A8B2E0DD218AE59CB71B211D7E
```

The PL/SQL version involves some conversion; [`dbms_crypto.hash()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_crypto.htm#i1002022) takes a `RAW` argument, so you have to convert the plain-text password to [`RAW`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#sthref182), then concatenate the extracted salt - which is already hex. (In the PL/SQL version in Pete Finnigan's blog you may notice that he has an explicit `hextoraw` call, so I'm simplifying a bit). So the argument passed to `dbms_crypto.hash` for your example would be the hex (OK, raw) equivalent of `ZK3002`, which is `5A4B33303032`, with the hex salt concatenated to that; so `5A4B333030321DB70EE23BFB23BDFD48`.

For the Java version you pass a byte array, but that means you need to convert the salt extracted from the stored password back from hex before tacking it on to the password; and since it's unlikely to have a useful string representation you might as well put it straight into a byte array. So, convert the password to a byte array, convert the salt into a byte array, and stick the two arrays together. That then becomes the value you pass to `MessageDigest`.

You can compare the hash this produces with the Oracle-hashed version, skipping the initial `S:` and the embedded salt.

Comment: So there is no other way than brute force to find his passwords. Not surprised.

Comment: @MatinKh - I don't think he particularly wanted to un-hash them (which is of course not possible, without brute-forcing them), just wanted to authenticate against the Oracle-hashed value. I'd probably consider only doing this the first time a user logged in, then re-hash the password in a non-Oracle way (maybe` bcrypt`, but whatever) and store that instead for future use. Depends why it has to change in the first place maybe.

Comment: Yeah I get it now. From the question I got this feeling that he is looking for a way for decrypting those encrypted passwords. (which would surprise me if anyone gave him the answer)

Comment: OK, tried that now - works perfectly. I also thought that the problem might relate to the hex/byte conversion but couldn't figure out how to build that in Java. Thanks a lot!