# Concatenate, sort and swap array in Java

Tags: java, sorting, object, swap, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two arrays into new array, sort in order, and swap two values of index.

I'm kind of new to java and only use C before so having a hard time handling an Object.

In main method it declares two object arrays
IntVector vector = new IntVector(3); and IntVector vector2 = new IntVector(3);

I can only do this if the types are int[], but I want to use as an object
How should I code the concat, sort, and swap method?

public class IntVector  {

```
private int[] items_;
private int itemCount_;

private IntVector(int[] data, int n) {
      items_ = data.clone();
      itemCount_ = n;
    }


 public IntVector(int itemSize)
 {
  itemCount_ =0;

  if(itemSize<1) itemSize =10;

  items_ = new int[itemSize];
 }

 public void push(int value)
 {
  if(itemCount_ + 1 >= items_.length)
   overflow();

  items_[itemCount_++] = value;
 }

 public void log()
 {
  for (int i=0 ; i<itemCount_; ++i)
  {
   System.out.print(items_[i]);

   if(i<itemCount_ -1)
    System.out.println();
  }
 }

 public void overflow()
 {
  int[] newItems = new int[items_.length * 2];

  for(int i=0 ; i<itemCount_; ++i)
  {
   newItems[i] = items_[i];
  }
  items_=newItems;
  }

 public int getValue(int index)
 {
  if(index < 0 || index >= itemCount_)
  {
   System.out.println("[error][IntVector][setValue] Incorrect index=" + index);
   return 0;
  }
  return items_[index];
 }

 public void setValue(int index, int value)
 {
  if(index < 0 || index >= itemCount_)
  {
   System.out.println("[error][IntVector][setValue] Incorrect index=" + index);
   return ;
  }
  items_[index] = value;
 }


public IntVector clone()
 {

    return new IntVector(items_, itemCount_);
 }

public IntVector concat()
 {

    return null;
 }

public IntVector sort()
 {

    return null;
 }

public IntVector swap()
 {

    return null;
 }



 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   IntVector vector = new IntVector(3);
   IntVector vector2 = new IntVector(3);

   vector.push(8);
   vector.push(200);
   vector.push(3);
   vector.push(41);

   IntVector cloneVector = vector.clone();

   vector2.push(110);
   vector2.push(12);
   vector2.push(7);
   vector2.push(141);
   vector2.push(-32);

   IntVector concatResult = vector.concat(vector2);
   IntVector sortResult = concatResult.sort();
   IntVector swapResult = sortResult.clone();


   //swapResult.swap(1,5);

   System.out.print("vector : "); vector.log();
   System.out.print("\n\ncloneVector : "); cloneVector.log();
   System.out.print("\n\nvector2 : "); vector2.log();
   System.out.print("\n\nconcatvector : "); concatResult.log();
   System.out.print("vector : "); vector.log();
   System.out.print("vector : "); vector.log();

 }
```

}

Comment: I can only code in this way when the types are array of int
public int[] concat2(int[] A, int[] B)
{
 int[] concat_ary = new int[10];
 for(int i=0 ; i<itemCount_ ; i++)
 {
 
  if(i<A.length)
   concat_ary[i]=A[i];
  else
   concat_ary[i]=B[i];
  
 }
 return concat_ary;
 
}

public void sort2(int[] A)
{
 for(int i=A.length-1 ; i>=0; i--)
 {
  for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
  {
   if(A[j]>A[j+1])
   {
    int temp =A[j];
    A[j]=A[j+1];
    A[j+1] =temp;
   }
  }
 }
}

}

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the Collections framework for this?

Comment: As owlstead suggested, I'd take a look at the [Collections Tail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: I'm guessing that this is an assignment of some kind, otherwise as everyone is suggesting just use Collections rather than re-implementing. If it is an assignment you're wanting help with it would be good to be clear about the constraints you are under, e.g. core java library only?

Comment: @owlstead fat fingers + iPad = bad idea :P ... Shame I can't fix it

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah, had the same thing with my mobile phone a few times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache Commons library has an [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) which you can use to concatenate arrays.

To sort the arrays you can use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) which is part of the standard SDK. There is [one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with a comparator if you want to custom sort

To swap your method takes no parameters so I am not sure what element you want to swap. If you want to elements in two indicies you could do

```
private swap (int pos1, int pos2) {
    //do some checking to ensure pos1 and pos2 exist here...
    int tmp = items_[pos1];
    items_[pos1] = items_[pos2];
    items_[pos2] = tmp;
}
```

But as everyone has said I would also recommend using the Collections framework. It will make the concatenation a lot simpler. And there is a dedicated [swap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29) method

### Edit

I have just found [how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80503/846476) which may help with the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do all of this in a typical Java way, you'd need the following:

a) Create two `int` arrays initialized with necessary values.

b) Convert the two arrays into `List` using the `Arrays` utility class. See the [`asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method.

c) Create an `ArrayList` and add the above two lists to it. See the [`addAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method.

d) Sort this `List` based on the natural order. See the [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method or create your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and apply the sorting.

e) Convert the `List` to an int array using the [`toArray(T[] t)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29)method.

The last `int` array you got should be the end result.

As @owlstead commented, using the Java Collections API would be lot simpler than going low level manipulating arrays yourself.