# How to concatenate two-dimensional arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

I have a situation where I need to concatenate two two-dimensional arrays.

```
Object[][] getMergedResults() {
    Object[][] a1 = getDataFromSource1();
    Object[][] a2 = getDataFromSource2();
    // I can guarantee that the second dimension of a1 and a2 are the same
    // as I have some control over the two getDataFromSourceX() methods

    // concat the two arrays
    List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for(Object[] entry: a1) {
        result.add(entry);
    }
    for(Object[] entry: a2) {
        result.add(entry);
    }
    Object[][] resultType = {};

    return result.toArray(resultType);
}
```

I have looked at the solutions for the concatenation of 1-dimensional arrays in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java) but have been unable to make it work for my two-dimensional arrays.

So far, the solution I have come up with is to iterate over both arrays and adding each member to a ArrayList and then returning toArray() of that array list. I'm sure there must be an easier solution, but have so far been unable to come with one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try

```
Object[][] result = new Object[a1.length + a2.length][];

System.arraycopy(a1, 0, result, 0, a1.length);
System.arraycopy(a2, 0, result, a1.length, a2.length);
```

Comment: Thank you. Strangely enough, this looks exactly like the one-dimensional solution proposed in the link I mentioned above. I had tried to adapt that to my two-dimensional issue but couldn't make it work. Now, looking at your solution I don't see what I'd done differently for it not to work. *scratches head*. Anyway, I'm glad I've got a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apache Commons Library - [ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll-boolean:A-boolean...-). Change only the index for second dimension and merge the whole lines.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like an interesting library, though I don't think I'll want to added dependency if the above code solves my problem. Still, I'll keep it in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I use for 2D array concatenation. It partly uses Sergio Nakanishi's answer, but adds the ability to concatenate in both directions.

```
/*
 * Define directions for array concatenation
 */
public static final byte ARRAY_CONCAT_HORIZ = 0, ARRAY_CONCAT_VERT = 1;

/*
 * Concatenates 2 2D arrays
 */
public static Object[][] arrayConcat(Object[][] a, Object[][] b, byte concatDirection)
{
    if(concatDirection == ARRAY_CONCAT_HORIZ && a[0].length == b[0].length)
    {
        return Arrays.stream(arrayConcat(a, b)).map(Object[].class::cast)
                    .toArray(Object[][]::new);
    }
    else if(concatDirection == ARRAY_CONCAT_VERT && a.length == b.length)
    {
        Object[][] arr = new Object[a.length][a[0].length + b[0].length];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arrayConcat(a[i], b[i]);
        }
        return arr;
    }
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("Attempted to concatenate arrays of incompatible sizes.");
}

/*
 * Concatenates 2 1D arrays
 */
public static Object[] arrayConcat(Object[] a, Object[] b)
{
    Object[] arr = new Object[a.length + b.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, arr, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, arr, a.length, b.length);
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logical Way-

```
    for(int j = 0; j < a.length+b.length; j++){
        if(j < a.length){
            ans[j] = a[j];
        }else{
            ans[j] = b[j-(a.length)];
        }
    }
```