# Java: Concatenating not specified number of 2d Arrays dinamically

Tags: java, arrays, object, 2d

I know that there were other questions related to this topic. 
But this is a little different.

Immagine that you have a program that gets every *some amount of time* an 2d Object (Object[][]) from the excel and it pass this to one method; this method needs to concatenate this 2d Object, so when it gets a flag that there is no more input, it passes this *potentially big* 2d object as a result to some other method...

1) You don't know how many excel documents will be sent , so how many 2d object will you get

2) every 2d object can have different num of columns and rows (ok this is not a big problem)

Is there a way in java to concatenate 2d objects into one? Wihout "killing" the memory.

Looking at this accepted anwer 
[How do you append two 2D array in java properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820905/how-do-you-append-two-2d-array-in-java-properly)
there is an append method, but each time it is called (and in this described case we don't know how many times could be called), it **recreates** an 2d array, and in my opition is not a best practice for this solution.

Looking at this accepted solution [How to concatenate two-dimensional arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722538/how-to-concatenate-two-dimensional-arrays-in-java) there is used an **arraycopy** solution, which how i understood is something similar to the previous solution... maybe a little better.

I know that would be possible to use some lists that could somehow rappresents this 2d object, or be parsed at the end in the 2d object, but:
***is there any way in java (good practice) to concatenate dinamically unown number of 2d object into 1?***

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like you need ArrayList< ArrayList < Object > > instead of Object[][]. If you use ArrayList, the different num of columns and rows aren't problems at all, and  you not "killing" the memory if you use addAll method. Moreover, you could use a core Java methods to concat ot ArrayLists without create your own manual methods.

For example, you can use something like this:

```
public List<ArrayList<Object>> concat (List<ArrayList<Object>> list1, List<ArrayList<Object>> list2) {
   if(list1.size() > list2.size()) {
      List<ArrayList<Object>> listBig = new ArrayList(list1); // or just list1 if we can change list1
      List<ArrayList<Object>> listSmall = list2;
   } else {
      List<ArrayList<Object>> listBig = new ArrayList(list2); // or just list1 if we can change list1
      List<ArrayList<Object>> listSmall = list1;
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < listSmall.size(); i++) {
      listBig[i].addAll(listSmall[i]); 
   }
   return listBig;
}
```

Comment: Tnx, but:

**1)** every time I call concat (and can be several times) , I need to make _new ArrayList (list1)_ ? (if every time first "if" passes)

**2)** the for loop is not good right? cause it can overwrite the listBig, the listBig[i] must start at the last element of listBig?