# Java : Adding to the end of the String

Tags: java

I have a String as  shown below

```
String result = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
List list = new ArrayList();

        list.add("One");
        list.add("One2");
        list.add("One3");
```

I have an ArrayList , and i want to add the String result , so that it should look like

```
["A","B","C","D","E","F","One","One2","One3"]
```

I have tried this way

```
String result = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
        result = result+"list.get(i)"
        }
```

could anybody please help .

Comment: `["A","B","C","D","E","F"]` is not a String. Can you clarify your intent?

Comment: See i get a response from a server that way , so for standalone purpose i did so

Comment: If it is a JSON response then you need to parse it using an appropriate object mapper (you may use the Jackson library for that purpose as I usually do).

Comment: @PreethiJain: If you're going to write something which looks like code, please make it *real code*. Otherwise it's very hard to know what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: it looks like java code, but definitely it's not

Comment: It's either `String result = "ABCDEF"` (a string) or `String[] result = {"A","B","C","D","E","F"}` (an array of strings), pick one

Comment: Please have a look on my post to see another approach to solv your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @assylias pointed out, your question seems to be unclear. Assuming that your variable "result" is a string, do the following:

```
String result = "\"A\",\"B\",\"C\",\"D\",\"E\",\"F\"";
List list = new ArrayList();

list.add("One");
list.add("One2");
list.add("One3");

for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
   result += ",\"" + list.get(i) +"\""
}
```

Then your output from "result" should be:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F","One","One2","One3"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty way to do that without too many walk around

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tester4 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] result = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("One");
        list.add("One2");
        list.add("One3");

        for(int i = result.length-1; i>= 0; i--) {

            list.add(0,result[i]);
        }

        for(String string : list) {
            System.out.println("Answer: " + string);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`["A","B","C","D","E","F"]` is not a String. try this...

```
String result = ""
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    result += list.get(i);
}
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

The variable "result" that you use is an Array of String, not a String.

If you want to have a list of string with those charatestics you should write:

```
String[] result = {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("One");
list.add("One2");
list.add("One3");
for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++)
{
   list.add(i, result[i]);
}
```

So you will put the elements of the array "result" in the  list before the others.

Comment: This is inefficient, you'll be moving those 3 "One" elements continuously. Rather start with something like `list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(result))` and append the `One`, `One2` and `One3`. Not to mention it's not compilable code.

Answer (score 0):

Result isn´t a String, it´s a String[]. So, if you want result to look like

> ["A","B","C","D","E","F","One","One2","One3"]

you need to put "One", "Two", "Three" in another String[] and then concatenate the two arrays, for example like it´s shown  [here :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(result)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Java` defining the array looks like: `String[] result = {"A","B","C"}`

```
String[] result = {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
List list = new ArrayList();

list.add("One");
list.add("One2");
list.add("One3");

List<String> newList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(result));
newList.addAll(list);
```

Output `newList`:

`[A, B, C, D, E, F, One, One2, One3]`