# Java - Adding two arrays together

Tags: java

How would I go about adding 2 arrays together?

For example if: 
array 1= [11,33,4] 
array 2= [1,5,4]

Then the resultant array should be c=[11,33,4,1,5,4];
Any help would beappreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything. If yes then please show us and let us know where exactly you are encountering problem.

Comment: This question should be locked as a dupe. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a third array, copy the two arrays in to it:

```
int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0,  a.length);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Apache Commons Lang.  It has a method named [addAll](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29).  Here's its description:

> Adds all the elements of the given arrays into a new array.
>
> The new array contains all of the element of array1 followed by all of the elements array2. When an array is returned, it is always a new array.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
combinedArray = ArrayUtils.addAll(array1, array2);
```

Comment: This seems like a needless introduction of an external library for a very small piece of functionality, no?

Comment: @raptortech97: No.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  I don't care how simple the wheel is/seems.  I've written methods that were one line long but still had a bug in it.  `ArrayUtils.addAll` is tested better than a hand-written `System.arraycopy` that accomplishes the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `c` array with a length equal to the sum of the lengths of the two arrays.  Then use [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy the contents of the original arrays into the new array, being careful to copy them into the destination array at the correct start index.

Comment: That works, but I like my answer better because with Commons Lang you don't have to "be careful".  The api doesn't let you make this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an arraylist since the size is not permanent. Then use a loop to add your array to it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html