# Merge two arrays together

Tags: java

How do I merge/concat two arrays to one? 
I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java) post, however I need a solution that can concat two different arrays that both extend the same class. eg foo1 extends Object and foo2 extends Object, then I need to concat 
foo1[] and foo2[] to an Object[] array.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Comment: How does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java not cover you? Duplicate.

Comment: What part of the solutions proposed in each of the answers to that question could not be implemented in your case?

Comment: As figuring out the right type seems to be problem it might be a good idea to share a little more thoughts about this with us. The chance that foo1 and foo2 both extend Object is pretty high in java. And if in all of these cases Object[] is the right choice the question is in fact kind of superfluous..

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, java `arrays` have fixed memory and size, so to concat two arrays you have to create a new one with the size of `arrOne.length + arrTwo.length` and just iterate over the values of arrays and add them to the new array.

```
Object[] arrThree = new Object[arrTwo.length + arrOne.length];
int index = arrTwo.length;

for (int i = 0; i < arrTwo.length; i++) {
    arrThree[i] = arrTwo[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < arrOne.length; i++) {
    arrThree[i + index] = arrOne[i];    
}
```

This would work without any additional utils - plain java. `arrOne` and `arrTwo` are considered as already existing ones.

Comment: `System.arraycopy(arrOne, 0, arrThree, 0, arrOne.length); System.arraycopy(arrTwo, 0, arrThree, arrOne.length, arrTwo.length);`

Comment: Oh, thanks. Didn't know about that. Example is here -http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm - in case the TS would like to see it. But still, it could be not clear for the TS.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

[ArrayUtils.addAll](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method. accord to doc

> Adds all the elements of the given arrays into a new array.
>
> The new array contains all of the element of array1 followed by all of
>   the elements array2. When an array is returned, it is always a new
>   array.

so you can use like

```
resultArray[] = ArrayUtils.addAll(firstArray, SecondArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

create your Object[] array,then do a first loop on your foo1[] to add manually to the object[],then repeat for foo2[].

barbarian,yet simple and efficient

Answer (score 1):

One liner solution:

```
Object[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(array1,array2);
```

Comment: Might want to mention where `ArrayUtils` comes from.

Comment: Oh right -- http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html . That works only if you have commons.lang

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create an Array of type object that is the combined length of the foo1[] + the length of the foo2[]. Then either iterate each array and add to the Object[] or use the answer in the link you provided: [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Or better still work with ArrayList instead and use the .addAll() method