# How to copy a array into another array that already has data in it?

Tags: java, arrays

How would I copy an array say

```
float arraytobecopied[] = {1.20,2.50,3.60};
```

to another array that has data in it already say

```
float newarray[] = {5.20,6.30,4.20};
```

I want to add the the `arraytobecopied` to the end of the new array and keep the values in the array. also as a side note this would be an on going process adding to the end of the array every time.

Should i just use a `for` loop? or is there a better way.
(Can't use Array) already tried:(

Comment: The answer to your question on how to join the two arrays is most definitely using ApacheCommons `ArrayUtils.addAll`, but since you asked is there a better way. I would recommend using `ArrayList<Float>` as you can just keep appending values to it when necessary.

Comment: Sweet thanks for the info but i cant use Array<list> ive tried it already and it doesnt work for me needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't increase the size of the original array. But you could create a new array, copy both source arrays into it, and assign your reference variable to it.

For example, here's a sketch of a simple implementation. (An alternative is to use `System.arraycopy()`.)

```
 float[] newerArray = new float[ newarray.length + arraytobecopied.length ];
 for ( int i = 0; i < newarray.length; ++i ) {
     newerArray[i] = newarray[i];
 }
 for ( int i = 0; i < arraytobecopied.length; ++i ) {
     newerArray[ newarray.length + i ] = arraytobecopied[i];
 }
 newarray = newerArray; // Point the reference at the new array
```

Alternatively, you could use a `java.util.ArrayList`, which automatically handles growing the internal array. Its `toArray()` methods make it easy to convert the list to an array when required.

Answer (score 13):

This question has been asked here before, You can see this page for the answer. [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Use `System.arraycopy`

`public static void arraycopy(Object src,
                             int srcPos,
                             Object dest,
                             int destPos,
                             int length)`

Comment: That assumes that the target array is long enough to hold all the values in both arrays.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest approach from a programming perspective is to use a `List<Float>` (if you can use `Float` values instead of `float`) or a third-party library such as [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) or [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) that provides dynamic arrays of primitives.

If you need to use a simple array of primitives (and not a wrapper class), you can use a couple of methods in the [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and [`java.lang.System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) classes to help:

```
int len1 = newarray.length;
int len2 = arraytobecopied.length;
float[] result = Arrays.copyOf(newarray, len1 + len2);
System.arraycopy(arraytobecopied, 0, result, len1, len2);
// result now contains the concatenation of newarray and arraytobecopied
```

Note that you cannot change the length of an array object; you can only reassign the variable to a new array (e.g., `newarray = result;`).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest can be:

```
List<Float> floats = new ArrayList(arraytobecopied);
floats.addAll(newarray);
arraytobecopied = floats.toArray(new float[0]);
```

Comment: List won't accept primitive types. `List<Float> floats = new ArrayList<Float>();`

Comment: I corrected it from float to Float. We can have lists of Float.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use anything from java.Util at all.

How about writing one method that updates the destination array with src array. Now when u copy elements make sure that the size is enough in destination array. Otherwise when you create a new array, create it with double size and copy the elements, this may help in avoiding a new array creation everytime and doing iterations to populate the complete array again after resizing.

Somewhat similar to how array list maintains size of array inside it.