# How to concat two char arrays in java?

Tags: java

How to concatenate two char arrays in java ?

```
char info[]=new char[10];
char data[]=new char[10];
char result[]=new char[40];
```

I need to concatenate `info` and `data`, and store the concatenation in `result`:

`result=info+data;`

How to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html

Answer (score 10):

It depends I guess.  The simpler approach would be just to convert the `char` arrays to a `String` and concaternate the `String`s.

A better approach would be to use `StringBuilder`

```
char info[] = new char[10];
char data[] = new char[10];


// Assuming you've filled the char arrays...

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
sb.append(info);
sb.append(data);

char result[] = sb.toString().toCharArray();
```

Comment: If he wants the output as a string that is a nice approach.

Comment: I don't think you want to append `result`. He says he wants `result = info + data`. In your case, the last line should be `result = sb.toString().toCharArray();`

Comment: @assylias Yeah I thought that to, I also thought that `sb.toString().toCharArray()` to get the character array back.  This of course assumes the OP wants to only use `char` arrays ;)

Comment: @AleksG Ah, that's true, missed that. Thanks

Comment: Love down votes without comment, makes me all warm and fuzzy inside :P

Comment: Just gave you a upvote even though it's old and full of solutions..

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
char result[] = new char[info.length + data.length];
System.arraycopy(info, 0, result, 0, info.length);
System.arraycopy(data, 0, result, info.length, data.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found one-line solution from the old Apache Commons Lang library: [ArrayUtils addAll()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5b%5d,%20T...%29)