# Add an array of string with another using for loop

Tags: java, android

Hi I use `for` loop to add the strings which is in array. Can anyone help me for the below code it shows error.

```
image = new String[] {"APP","FIELD","KYC"};

image2 = new String[] {"MEMORANDUM","ASSOCIATION"};
```

Now using for loop or any method I need the same **image** array as

```
image = new String[] {"APP","FIELD","KYC","MEMORANDUM","ASSOCIATION"};
```

Comment: what is the error? show us your for loop

Comment: The code you posted should not show any error. There is a number of ways to achieve what you are trying to achieve, with or without loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this can be possible without loop. Use [ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)

```
String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(image, image2);
```

---

Here is a solution with array to/from `List` conversions.

```
String[] image = new String[] {"APP","FIELD","KYC"};
String[] image2 = new String[] {"MEMORANDUM","ASSOCIATION"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(image));
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(image2));
String[] result = list.toArray(new String[]{});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Output will be the same as you required in question.

---

As Mena suggested another solution can be [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
String[] image = new String[] {"APP","FIELD","KYC"};
String[] image2 = new String[] {"MEMORANDUM","ASSOCIATION"};
String[] result = new String[image.length + image2.length]; 

// copies an array from the specified source array
System.arraycopy(image, 0, result, 0, image.length);
System.arraycopy(image2, 0, result, image.length, image2.length);

// Now you can use result for final array
```

Read more about [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Comment: You should specify this requires Apache Commons.

Comment: @Mena I added the link.

Comment: Ah yes just seen the edit now. Fair enough. Although I would be even more explicit about the fact that your solution requires a dependency in the project (and there are alternate solutions that don't).

Comment: @Mena solution added and updated duplicate link.

Comment: Better ;) You've got my +1. Could have used [arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) as well for this.

Comment: @Mena Hey you were right.. I check the method and its working for the purpose.. thanks for introducing me with a nice method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
    ArrayList<String> image = new ArrayList<String>();
    image.add("APP");
    image.add("FIELD");
    image.add("KYC");

    ArrayList<String> image2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    image2.add("MEMORANDUM");
    image2.add("ASSOCIATION");

    image.addAll(image2);

    for(String i:image){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java by default do not has such util. What you can do is to use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

```
public static void copy(Object[] a, Object... b) {

  int alen = a.length;
  int blen = b.length;

  Object[] c = new Object[alen + blen);

  System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, alen);
  System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, alen, blen);

  return c;
}
```

You may wish to use the generics

```
public static <T> void copy(T[] a, T... b) {

  int alen = a.length;
  int blen = b.length;

  T[] c = (T[]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass(),alen + blen);

  System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, alen);
  System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, alen, blen);

  return c;
}
```

But all this is required if you are really attached to Arrays, but it seams that you change the size during program flow. Reconsider using a `List<String>` that will allow you to store strings and extend it frellly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] image = new String[] { "APP", "FIELD", "KYC" };
    String[] image2 = new String[] { "MEMORANDUM", "ASSOCIATION" };     

    String[] image3 = new String[image.length+image2.length];       

    for (int i = 0; i <image.length; i++) {
        image3[i] = image[i];

    }

    for (int i = image.length; i>=0 && i < image3.length; i++) {
        image3[i] = image2[i-3];
    }


    //Check if image3 contains the elements you need.
    for(String imageData:image3)
    {
        System.out.println(imageData);
    }

}
```

This is not a generic solution. It just solves what you need. Can you elaborate more on what are you trying to do?