# Combine two integer arrays into one array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I've seen similar questions and none provide the answer that I'm looking for, so I apologize in advance if this is considered a duplicate.
I'm trying to combine arrays {1, 2, 3} and {4, 5, 6} into {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. What am I doing incorrectly? I'm super new to java. Sorry if the question is stupid.

```
public class combine {
  public static void main(String[]args){

  int[]a = {1, 2, 3};
  int[]b = {4, 5, 6};
  int[]c = new int[a+b];
  for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
  System.out.print(c[i]+" ");
}
public static int[]merge(int[]a, int[]b){
  int[]c = new int[a.length+b.length];
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
     c[i] = a[i];

     for(int j=0; j<b.length; j++)
        c[i++]=b[j];
        return c;
}
}
```

Comment: in some place call `merge`, and actually is not a merge is like `concatenate` :P

Comment: It's also defined locally in the method; it would never print the correct array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two arrays in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
int[]c = new int[a+b];
```

You need to call your merge method and assign the result to the array like :

```
int[]c = merge(a,b);
```

Also you for loop should be :

```
int[]c = merge(a,b);
for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++)
    System.out.print(c[i]+" ");
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't do it yourself, use [`System.arrayCopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to copy both arrays into a new array of the combined size. That's much more efficient, as it uses native OS code.

Comment: is it because of deep copying vs shallow copying?

Comment: No, both versions are shallow, but System.arrayCopy() uses OS routines instead of Java abstractions.

Answer (score 5):

```
  String a[] = { "A", "E", "I" };
  String b[] = { "O", "U" };
  List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a));
  list.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));
  Object[] c = list.toArray();
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Comment: I know the code is pretty clear but it's always best to provide explanation of what you're doing.  Plain code with no explanation tends to get flagged for deletion around here.  Also - welcome to SO

Comment: Thanks @StormeHawke , I am new to this community....will take care in future.... the code was self explanatory so didn't provide comment for it.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code, I hope it's useful for you

```
String a[] = new String[4];
    String b[] = new String[2];
    String[] ab = new String[a.length + b.length];
    int i, j, d, s = 0;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first array");

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = x.next();
        for (d = i; d < a.length; d++) {
            ab[d] = a[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Enter the second array");

    for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        b[j] = x.next();
        for (d = a.length + j; d < ab.length; d++)
            ab[d] = b[j];
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The new array is !!");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    for (s = 0; s < ab.length; s++) {
        System.out.print(ab[s] + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MerginTwoArray{
public static void mergingarr(int x[], int y[])
{
    int len=x.length+y.length;
    int arr[]=new int[len];
    //create a variable j which will begin zeroth index of second array
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(i<x.length)
        {
            arr[i]=x[i];
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i]=y[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for(int i:arr)
    {
        System.out.print(i+ " ");
    }
}
public static void main(String... args)
{
    mergingarr(new int[]{1,2,3}, new int[]{4,5,6});
}
```

}

Hope this is clear to you

Answer (score 1):

One more way of concatenating 2 arrays is:

```
System.out.println("Enter elements for a: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int num = in.nextInt();
    a[i] = num;
}

System.out.println("Enter elements for b: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int num = in.nextInt();
    b[i] = num;
}

void merge() {
    int c[] = new int[10];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));  // merged array 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
package array;

public class Combine {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 int[]a = {1,2,3,4};
 int[]b = {4,16,1,2,3,22};
 int[]c = new int[a.length+b.length];
 int count=0;

  for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
       c[i]=a[i];
       count++;
    }

 for(int j=0;j<b.length;j++)
    {
       c[count++]=b[j];
    }

        for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
        System.out.print(c[i]+" ");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my solution (you can eventually sort it if need be):

```
public static int[] mergeAndSortIntArrays(int[] firstInt, int[] secondInt){

    List<Integer> merged = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i<firstInt.length; i++){
        merged.add(firstInt[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<secondInt.length; i++){
        merged.add(secondInt[i]);
    }

    Collections.sort(merged);
    int[] result=new int[merged.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<merged.size(); i++){
        result[i]=merged.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   int a[] = {
        5, 10, 15, 25
    };
    int b[] = {
        12, 5, 7, 9
    };
    int c[] = new int[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);

    }
    System.out.println("**************");
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        System.out.println(b[j]);
    }
    //int[] c=merge(a,b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        c[i] = a[i];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int k = 4; k < 8; k++) {
            c[k] = b[i];
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(c[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Merge two array without arraylist.

```
    public class Main {


    static int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    static int b[] = {5, 6, 7, 8};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        int totalLengh = a.length + b.length;

        int c[] = new int[totalLengh];

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalLengh; i++) {

            if (i < a.length) {

                c[i] = a[i];

            } else {
                c[i] = b[j];
                j++;
            }

            System.out.println("" + c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class MergeArrays {
    public static void main(String[]args){
         int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
         int[] b = {4, 5, 6};
         int[] c = new int[a.length+b.length];// Here length of int[] c will be 6
         int count = 0;

         //looping to store the value length of i
         for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) { 
             c[i] = a[i];
             count++;
          }
        //looping to store the value length of j
          for(int j = 0;j<b.length;j++) { 
             c[count++] = b[j];
          }
        //looping to retrieve the value of c
          for(int i = 0;i<c.length;i++) 
              System.out.print(c[i]);// Displaying looped value/output in single line at console 

    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public static void main(String[]args){

        int[]a = {1, 2, 3};
        int[]b = {4, 5, 6};
        int[]c ;
        c=merge(a,b);
        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++)
            System.out.print(c[i]+" ");
    }
    public static int[]merge(int[]a, int[]b){
        int[]c = new int[a.length+b.length];
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            c[i] = a[i];
        System.out.println(i);
        for(int j=0; j<b.length; j++)
            c[i++]=b[j];
        return c;
    }
```