# how to combine two java arrays into one

Tags: java, arrays

this is what i have so far

```
int[] startInts = Arrays.copyOfRange(myInts, count+1, myInts.length); // first half of array
int[] endInts = Arrays.copyOfRange(myInts, count+1, myInts.length); // other half of array

int[] newInts = new int[startInts.length + endInts.length];
System.arraycopy(startInts, 0, newInts, 0, startInts.length);
System.arraycopy(endInts, 0, newInts, startInts.length, endInts.length);

myInts = newInts;
```

But all this does is give me a number.

It doesn't really merge the two arrays into one array. Any help with how to do this.

## Solution

```
int[] startInts = Arrays.copyOfRange(myInts, myInts[0], index); // first half of array
        int[] endInts = Arrays.copyOfRange(myInts, count+1, myInts.length); // other half of array

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(startInts));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(endInts));
        
        int[] newInts = new int[startInts.length + endInts.length];
        System.arraycopy(startInts, 0, newInts, 0, startInts.length);
        System.arraycopy(endInts, 0, newInts, startInts.length, endInts.length);
```

Comment: Please do a search before asking similar questions

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran there was no answer to that so yea..

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran no real definite answer to the problem, meaning no real solution.

Comment: can you refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316526/combine-two-integer-arrays-into-one-array-in-java it might be helpful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class System**

Method

```
arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at
>   the specified position, to the specified position of the destination
>   array.

Look [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) for all set of functions

---

**EDIT**

```
int[] startInts = Arrays.copyOfRange(myInts, count+1, myInts.length); // first half of array
int[] endInts = Arrays.copyOfRange(myInts, count+1, myInts.length); // other half of array
```

The possible issue that you face here is that the `startInts` and `endInts` are the same, so its not the first half and second half, its just first half and first Half.

Comment: if you see the code i did this

Comment: the problem is with the `startInts` and `endInts` both are the same.so you get an array with double the size of startInts like `[endInts,endInts]`

Comment: you are right i fixed it, i mustve pressed ctrl+z and didnt notice, but i still dont get the desired output

Comment: print both the array and check what's the array value for `startInts` and `endInts`

Comment: Wow it worked, i cant believe it was just a simple typo causing all the wrong outputs. Thank you so much for pointing that out i really was not even paying attention to that.

Solution is on top

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

when ArrayUtils is a class from Apache Commons Lang library

Answer (score 0):

why not use ArrayList's

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();

a.add("a1");
a.add("a2");

b.add("b1");
b.add("b2");

ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.addAll(a);
c.addAll(b);

System.out.println(c.toString());
```

Of course if you want to start out with real `arrays` then you can convert them into `ArrayList` using `Arrays.asList(array)`

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] both = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

or

```
static String[] concat(String[] a, String[] b) {
   String[] c= new String[a.length+b.length];
   System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
   System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
   return c;
}
```

Comment: id prefer native OS java code

Comment: this gives me a total of all things concatenated, not the array of the things concatenated. any way to change this?

Comment: I do not know what you mean.

Comment: when i do this, it adds array1.length + array2.length and returns the total of elements. it does not return the elements.

ex. it returns this: 10
instead of this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10