# How can add append two array by method?

Tags: netbeans-8

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

```
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 4 };
int b[] = { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[]c = new int[a.length+b.length];
int count = 0;
    System.out.println(result(c[a.length+b.length]));
}
public static int result () {
    // TODO code application logic here

     for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {

    System.out.print(c[i] + " ");
    int count = 0;

    return result ;
     }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two integer arrays into one array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316526/combine-two-integer-arrays-into-one-array-in-java)

Comment: thanks , but the result give first 3 then 1 2 3 4 5 6 how can remove number 3

Comment: 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: it solved , thanks alot