# How do I concatenate all string elements of several arrays into one single array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

How do I concatenate, or append, all of the arrays that contain text strings into a single array? From the following code:

```
    String nList[] = {"indonesia", "thailand", "australia"};

    int nIndex[] = {100, 220, 100};

    String vkList[] = {"wounded", "hurt"};

    int vkIndex[] = {309, 430, 550};

    String skList[] = {"robbed", "detained"};

    int skIndex[] = {120, 225};

    String nationality = "";

    //System.out.println(nationality);
```

I want to store all strings of all three string-containing arrays:

```
    String nList[] = {"indonesia", "thailand", "australia"};

    String vkList[] = {"wounded", "hurt"};

    String skList[] = {"robbed", "detained"};
```

into a single array, say array1[].

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(nList));
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(vkList));
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(skList));

String[] result = (String[])temp.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the content of each array to a temporary `List` and then convert it's content to a `String[]`.

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(nList));
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(vkList));
temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(skList));

String[] result = new String[temp.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
    result[i] = (String) temp.get(i);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use Guava's [ObjectArrays#concat(T[] first, T[] second, Class< T > type)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArrays.html#concat%28T%5B%5D,%20T%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Class%29) method, which returns a new array that contains the concatenated contents of two given arrays. For example:

```
String[] concatTwoArrays = ObjectArrays.concat(nList, vkList, String.class);
String[] concatTheThirdArray = ObjectArrays.concat(concatTwoArrays, skList, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String[] join(String [] ... parms) {
 // calculate size of target array
 int size = 0;
 for (String[] array : parms) {
   size += array.length;
 }

 String[] result = new String[size];

 int j = 0;
 for (String[] array : parms) {
   for (String s : array) {
     result[j++] = s;
   }
 }
return result;
}
```

Just define your own join method. Found @ http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0636.html