# How to merge two File[] with different folders into a single File[] in Java

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to list files from two different directories in an Android device in order to upload them to a server.

To do that, I'm getting the directory files under a File type and then throwing both listFiles() into correspondents File[] types.

```
    String d1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Download/";
    String d2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/DCIM/Camera";

    File DirDocuments = new File(d1);
    File DirCamera = new File(d2);

    File[] ListDocuments = DirDocuments.listFiles();
    File[] ListCamera = DirCamera.listFiles();
```

I've tryed to merge then and uploadign using just a single "for" loop

```
    List<String> listTemp = new ArrayList<String>();

    for( int i=0; i< ListaDocuments.length; i++)
    {
            listTemp.add( ListaDocuments[i].getName() );
    }
    for( int i=0; i< ListaCamera.length; i++)
    {
            listTemp.add( ListaCamera[i].getName() );
    }

    File[] DirTotal = (String[]) listTemp.toArray(); //toArray gives Object[] and cannot be converted to File[], so I used String[]
```

But my app just stop and exits. What am I doing wrong?

Do anyone knows how can I merge ListDocuments and ListCamera into a single File[]?

Thanks in advance. (sorry about my typos and bad english)

Comment: Last line shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could join both arrays' contents into a `List<File>` and not a `List<String>`:

```
    List<File> listTemp = new ArrayList<File>();

    for( int i=0; i< ListaDocuments.length; i++) {
            listTemp.add( ListaDocuments[i] );
    }
    for( int i=0; i< ListaCamera.length; i++)
    {
            listTemp.add( ListaCamera[i] );
    }
```

<sub>Notice there are other ways of joining those arrays (i.e. Apache Commons Collections [`ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29) as explained in [How to concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/80476/851811) and numerous duplicates).</sub>

And then just use the [other version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T[]%29) of `toArray()`:

```
File[] DirTotal = listTemp.toArray(new File[0]);
```

`toArray()` without arguments will always return an `Object[]`. The version that takes an argument will fill up the passed array if it's big enough, and return a newly allocated array in case there's not enough room. The returned array is of the same type than the passed one, so if you pass a `File[]`, you get a `File[]`.

Comment: Neither add or addAll are working. I've got the error:- 
The method addAll(Collection<? extends File>) in the type List<File> is not applicable for the arguments (File[])

Comment: Thanks for this usefull suggestion, anyway. Due to the comments, I need to study the arrays subject further and deeply. If you have more ideas, please let me know.

Comment: It seems you're using `addAll()` method defined in [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). `ArrayUtils.addAll()` belongs to a third-party library called [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) (you need to download it and place it on your classpath in order to use it). `listTemp.add(ListDocuments[i])` should be working fine, tho. `ListDocuments` is a `File[]`, so `ListDocuments[i]` is a `File`. It is fine as long as the `List` you're adding the elements to is a `List<File>`, isn't it?

Comment: It seems that the libraries that comes with Android SDK are somehow slightly different than the "usual". I solved this with `files.addAll   ( Arrays.asList( file.listFiles() )  );`.

Comment: The entire function is `public List<File> listFiles (String... paths) {
         List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
 
         for ( String path : paths   ) {
             File file =  new File(path); 
             File[]  currentFileList =  file.listFiles(); 
             files.addAll   ( Arrays.asList( file.listFiles() )  );
       }
 
     return files;
 }`. I'm sending the two directories as parameters `String d1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Download/"; 
        String d2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/DCIM/Camera/";`

Comment: the function call is `List<File> listTemp = new ArrayList<File>();
        listTemp = listFiles(d1,d2);`

Comment: @SpaceVulcan Glad you solved it :-) Remember to upvote helpful answers and mark as accepted the one that solved your problem. If none of them qualifies (it looks like it didn't get through in your last comment), remember you can post your own answer and accept it. It will make it easier for future visitors of the question to identify a solution to the problem, and will also mark this question as resolved.

Comment: Thanks Xavi! I still don't have enough reputation to vote, but I choosed your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the last line is casting to String array but the variable is defined as a File array.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 Object[] DirTotal =  listTemp.toArray();
```

But why you can't use this temp list?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void mergeFiles(File[] files, File mergedFile) {

    FileWriter fstream = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {
        fstream = new FileWriter(mergedFile, true);
         out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (File f : files) {
        System.out.println("merging: " + f.getName());
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.write(aLine);
                out.newLine();
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

```
        String sourceFile1Path = "/mnt/sdcard/s1/t1.txt";
String sourceFile2Path = "/mnt/sdcard/s2/t2.txt";

String mergedFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/merge/t.txt";

File[] files = new File[2];
files[0] = new File(sourceFile1Path);
files[1] = new File(sourceFile2Path);

File mergedFile = new File(mergedFilePath);

mergeFiles(files, mergedFile);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use `addAll()` method in which is available in `java.util` package.