# Concatenating Java Arrays in a Loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, concatenation

I am writing a code for a Signals Software. The summary of logic goes as: users input --> String--> split at white spaces--> ArrayPerWord --> SignalArrayPerArrayPerWord. Output is loop. Up to here my code works well. Only the remaining part left is how to join this loop-output  in a sequence. I am searching  for concatenating these arrays like String concatenation as:

```
str=str+str1;
```

something like:

```
SignalArrayPerArrayPerWord=SignalArrayPerArrayPerWord   + SignalArrayPerArrayPerWord1;
```

in other words:

```
array=array+array1;
```

I need help at this last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will concatenate arrays of same types:

```
String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

Its similar to something like this:

```
ArrayUtils.addAll(["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]) = ["a", "b", "c", "1", "2", "3"]
```

Further details: [doc link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)

There are multiple ways of concatenating java arrays efficiently, check this stackoverflow post too to find the best example:

[stackoverflow post link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Can I get the result as :{"a", "b", "c", "1", "2", "3"} or I'll have to get it manually?

Comment: If you store the result in a array and print that then you will get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addAll` method with `List<Integer>`. Look at following example.

```
Integer[] arr={1,2,3};
Integer[] arr2={4,5,9};

List<Integer> res=new ArrayList<>();

res.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
res.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr2));

System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can inspire from the following byte array concatanetion example.

```
   public static byte[] concatByteArrays(byte[]... arrays) {
      // Determine the length of the result array
      int totalLength = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
         totalLength += arrays[i].length;
      }

      // create the result array
      byte[] result = new byte[totalLength];

      // copy the source arrays into the result array
      int currentIndex = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
         System.arraycopy(arrays[i], 0, result, currentIndex, arrays[i].length);
         currentIndex += arrays[i].length;
      }

      return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayUtils.addAll(array1, array2, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use List addAll Method..

```
List<String> signalArrayPerArrayPerWord = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> signalArrayPerArrayPerWord1 = new ArrayList<String>();

List<String> concatArray = new ArrayList<String>();

//concat
concatArray.addAll(signalArrayPerArrayPerWord);
concatArray.addAll(signalArrayPerArrayPerWord1);
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

and in loop use sb.append( "loop element at index" );