# How to merge arrays in JAVA without duplicates and not using built-in functions?

Tags: java

Lets say I have two arrays of integer and I want to merge them without duplicates.

I know I can add them in Set and then can retrieve them as arraylist.

But without using any built-in function how to do it?

Comment: This is more of an algorithm question rather than a java one

Comment: Since youre using Set and ArrayList you will have to use inbuilt functions for them.

Comment: Create array with the combined size, append the two arrays, sort, iterate over and add each element that's different from the previous to a new array. What have _you_ tried? And really, why would you not want to use the built-in methods?

Comment: [how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of code but here is a sample..

```
    try{
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        int[] b = {5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int[] c = new int[a.length+b.length];
        int[] fin = new int[a.length+b.length];
        int i = 0;
        for(int j : fin){
            fin[i++] = -1;
        }
        i = 0;
        for(int j : a){
            c[i++] = j;
        }
        for(int j : b){
            c[i++] = j;
        }
        boolean check = false;
        for(int j = 0,k = 0; j < c.length; j++){
            for(int l : fin){
                if( l == c[j] )
                    check = true;
            }
            if(!check){
                fin[k++] = c[j];
            } else check = false;
        }

    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what if we swap a and b ? and input like this int[] b = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
   int[] a = { 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want to merge them, since an array has an ordering of its elements.

You can just add one after the other (easiest) or "zip" them (one element from A, then one from B, then another from A, etc).

The main problem is that you have to do a check in your new array whether it already contains a value you're trying to add. This is easiest with built-in functions and implementations, like [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). There are Set implementations, like HashSet, which give you constant-time performance for looking up values and inserting them.

I really advise you to just do it the "usual" way and not try and reinvent the wheel.

I find this quite readable:

```
 static int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {
     Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
     set.addAll(Arrays.asList(b)); // skips duplicate as per Set implementation

     return set.toArray(new int[0]);
 }
```

This uses both duplication and built-in methods, but it's clear and concise.

Comment: Yes, easiest would be implementation of Sets but I am asked not to use built-in functions. It is a test.

Comment: Well, please don't post homework assignments here. What is meant by "built-in functions"? Can you use ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

```
private Set<Integer> mergeWithoutDuplicates(int[] a, int[] b) {
  Set<Integer> set1= new HashSet<Integer>(a.length+b.length);
  for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      set1.add(a[i]);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
      set1.add(b[i]);
  }
  return set1;
```

}

This function should serve your purpose