# How does the System.arraycopy method work?

Tags: java, arrays

A sample of the statement to type when using the method is

```
System.arraycopy(data, i, data, i+1, data.length-i-1);
```

The way it works according to my book is that the system move all element from `i` onward one position up. But intuitively I will think that the method will move all the element after `i` one position down. So there is empty space to put the copied element.

I am confused now as to how to move elements around in the same array. What does the statement really say?

Comment: Here are the docs which seem to be comprehensive: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)

Comment: Read the Javadoc like everybody else does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate two arrays in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `System.arraycopy` is

```
System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos,
                 Object dest, int destPos,
                 int length)
```

Therefore, this code copies

```
data[i .. (i + n - i - 1)] = data[i..(n-1)]
```

to

```
data[i+1 .. (i+1 + n-i-1)] = data[i+1..n]
```

(where the range includes the front but excludes the back, and `n = data.length`)

and thus leaves a "blank" spot at `data[i]`. Graphically:

```
       [0] [1] [2] [3] ... [i] [i+1] [i+2] ... [n-2] [n-1]
   src                     |-----------------------|
   dest                        |-------------------------|
```

Comment: I got too many of these kinds questions. Where do you seek help when you study on your own?

Comment: Heh, this site. That, and being able to read the documentation. (And, uh, like 18 years of doing this...)

Comment: Will the elements that moved have different index than before ?

Comment: The elements are moved to a new position, so in a sense, yes.