# Can't grasp how to use System.arraycopy();

Tags: java

I am attempting to copy all of the elements in an array into another one, however I am not grasping the concept of System.arraycopy(). Yes, I have researched into it and can't grasp the concept.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the System.arraycopy method work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517893/how-does-the-system-arraycopy-method-work)

Comment: I have already looked at that, but in my eyes that is copying one element to the array.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to answer here, and try to be simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters of arraycopy,

```
arraycopy(Object source, int sourceIndex, Object destination, int destinationIndex, int length);
```

An Example, Lets say we have 2 arrays each with 5 elements.

```
int arrayOne[] = {10,20,30,40,50}; // 5 Elements Each.
int arrayTwo[] = {2,4,6,8,10};
```

If we want to replace the 3rd element (2nd Index) of arrayTwo[2] with the 5th Element (4th Index) of arrayOne[4] we do the following.

```
System.out.println("Before (System.array.copy): "+arrayTwo[2]);

System.arraycopy(arrayOne,4,arrayTwo,2,1);

System.out.println("After (System.array.copy) : "+arrayTwo[2]);
```

The Output is as follows.

```
Before System.array.copy: 6
After System.array.copy : 50
```

Comment: Working now. Appreciate it.