# Insert an arg as first element to head manually in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, spring-security

I'm writing log system for Spring MVC. I will send userId to procedure.

```
public Object execProc(String storedProcedure, RowMapper rowMapper,
    Object... args)
```

I need to insert element head of args, how can I do?
Ex.

```
int userId = 9;
args.push(userId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply wish to add a new element as the head of the array an easy way is to create a new array and copy the elements using `System.arraycopy`. Then the new head-element can be added to index 0 as in the example below.

```
int userId = 9;
Object[] args = new Object[]{"a", "list", "of", "args"}; // the "old" array
Object[] theNewArray = new Object[args.length + 1]; // a new array, 1 element bigger
System.arraycopy(args, 0, theNewArray, 1, args.length); // copy everything
theNewArray[0] = userId; // and insert you head element

// From now on, use "theNewArray"
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `execProc` has vararg

```
execProc("your stored procedure here", myRowMapper, userId, firstArg, secondArg, ...);
```

If you need to merge your parameters before calling the method, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/80559/834

Comment: i get userId from Session, And I have more than 200 procedure which I had already written. I want to add into head of args.