# How to append one or more ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, append

I am trying to append the data's of one or more ArrayList values into another ArrayList is it possible and may i know how ?

Example code is given below

```
private static final Pattern DIR_SEPORATOR = Pattern.compile("/");
    private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] rootFolders = this.getStorageDirectories();

          if (rootFolders == null) {
           return;
          }
          int rl = rootFolders.length;

          File[] filelists = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < rl; i++) {
           String path = rootFolders[i];
           File target = new File(path + "/DCIM/");
           if (target.exists()) {
            filelists = target.listFiles();
               File[] filelist1  =  filelists;

           }
           File target2 = new File(path + "/DCIM/100ANDRO/");
           if (target2.exists()) {
               File[] filelist = target.listFiles();
            // Existing image to DB
            //IntialLoad(target2, Json_SupportedExtensionFromServer,CF,DP);
           }
          }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why add the extra incorrect code formatting tags that only disable syntax highlighting?

Comment: where in your code you want to concatenate two arraylist ? I can only see on arraylist and lots of arrays

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to "concatenate" two arrays (not `ArrayList`s). You need to use `ArrayUtils.addAll()` as described here:

[How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`Arraylistname.addAll(new ArraList())` try this code, I am also using this to Combine two `Arraylist`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your File[] arrays to an ArrayList before adding to your ArrayList, like this:

```
fileList.addAll(Arrays.asList(filelist1));
```