# How to join multiple single arrays into one large single array

Tags: java, arrays

So I gathered tokens from multiple lines of a text file and put those tokens into an array called tokens. With this code.

```
    scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            if ((line = scanner.nextLine()).charAt(0) != '#') {
                tokens = line.split(",");
            }
        }
```

(Its all in a try catch block)

I need to put all of those String tokens into a single array, how would I do this.
My new array is stringTokens [] = new String [countLines *4].

The while loop redefines the elements in tokens with each iteration, how do I save those old elements in stringTokens and add the new elements tokens will get into stringTokens as well.

Comment: appen tokens to stringTokens.

Comment: That's not compressing, that's joining arrays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Comment: Also you might consider using List instead, it will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `ArrayList<String>` for that, and when you need it as array, you can convert it to one:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
scanner = new Scanner(file);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    if ((line = scanner.nextLine()).charAt(0) != '#') {
        for(String s : line.split(",")) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
}
stringTokens = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: yeah @minecraftshamrock is correct, you can use Lists here, they are dynamic and can be appended

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using [ArrayLists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). They are essentially mutable arrays, with no specified size (the array "grows"* as you add elements.) and adding each token to your list of strings.

```
ArrayList<String> stringTokens = new ArrayList<String>();

...
for(String s : line.split(",")) {
        stringTokens.add(s);
}
```

*Capacity doubles when needed.