# Java eqivalent method of "splice(a,b,...)" in JavaScript method

Tags: java, javascript, splice

`someArray.splice(a,b,...)` method in JavaScript adds or removes items to/from array. What could be good and simple solution to implement such method in Java language? Assume we have `String[]` array.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to resize array then you probably should be using `List` instead of array. This will give you `addAll(index, Collection)` which you can use as `addAll(index, Arrays.aslList("foo", "bar"))`

Comment: In Java, arrays cannot be added to (grown) . Use `ArrayList` for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a Java implementation of the `Array.prototype.splice()` method as per the [JavaScript MDN specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
  public static <T>T[] splice(final T[] array, int start) {
    if (start < 0)
      start += array.length;

    return splice(array, start, array.length - start);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T>T[] splice(final T[] array, int start, final int deleteCount) {
    if (start < 0)
      start += array.length;

    final T[] spliced = (T[])Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), array.length - deleteCount);
    if (start != 0)
      System.arraycopy(array, 0, spliced, 0, start);

    if (start + deleteCount != array.length)
      System.arraycopy(array, start + deleteCount, spliced, start, array.length - start - deleteCount);

    return spliced;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T>T[] splice(final T[] array, int start, final int deleteCount, final T ... items) {
    if (start < 0)
      start += array.length;

    final T[] spliced = (T[])Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), array.length - deleteCount + items.length);
    if (start != 0)
      System.arraycopy(array, 0, spliced, 0, start);

    if (items.length > 0)
      System.arraycopy(items, 0, spliced, start, items.length);

    if (start + deleteCount != array.length)
      System.arraycopy(array, start + deleteCount, spliced, start + items.length, array.length - start - deleteCount);

    return spliced;
  }
```

The following JUnit code tests this implementation:

```
@Test
  public void testSplice() {
    final String[] array = new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"c", "d", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, 0, 2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "d", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, 1, 2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, 2, 2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, 3, 2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, Arrays.splice(array, 4, 2));
    try {
      Arrays.splice(array, 5, 2);
      Assert.fail("Expected ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
    }
    catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }

    try {
      Arrays.splice(array, -2, 3);
      Assert.fail("Expected ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
    }
    catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, Arrays.splice(array, -2, 2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, -3, 2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, -4, 2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "d", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, -5, 2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"c", "d", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, -6, 2));
    try {
      Arrays.splice(array, -7, 2);
      Assert.fail("Expected ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
    }
    catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {}, Arrays.splice(array, 0));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a"}, Arrays.splice(array, 1));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b"}, Arrays.splice(array, 2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}, Arrays.splice(array, 3));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, Arrays.splice(array, 4));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, Arrays.splice(array, 5));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, 6));
    try {
      Arrays.splice(array, 7);
      Assert.fail("Expected ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
    }
    catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, Arrays.splice(array, -1));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, Arrays.splice(array, -2));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"}, Arrays.splice(array, -3));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b"}, Arrays.splice(array, -4));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a"}, Arrays.splice(array, -5));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {}, Arrays.splice(array, -6));
    try {
      Arrays.splice(array, -7);
      Assert.fail("Expected NegativeArraySizeException");
    }
    catch (final NegativeArraySizeException e) {
    }

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"x", "y", "z", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, 0, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "x", "y", "z", "d", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, 1, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "x", "y", "z", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, 2, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, 3, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "x", "y", "z"}, Arrays.splice(array, 4, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    try {
      Arrays.splice(array, 5, 2, "x", "y", "z");
      Assert.fail("Expected ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
    }
    catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "x", "y", "z"}, Arrays.splice(array, -2, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, -3, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "b", "x", "y", "z", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, -4, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"a", "x", "y", "z", "d", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, -5, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"x", "y", "z", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, Arrays.splice(array, -6, 2, "x", "y", "z"));
    try {
      Arrays.splice(array, -7, 2, "x", "y", "z");
      Assert.fail("Expected ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
    }
    catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }
  }
```

**Edit:** As @denys-séguret pointed out correctly, this implementation differs from the JavaScript spec as it does not mutate/modify the original array. Instead, this implementation returns a new array instance.

**Edit:** This implementation is available with the following maven artifact, at the given maven repo:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.safris.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>mvn.repo.safris.org</id>
      <url>http://mvn.repo.safris.org/m2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Please fix your introduction, it doesn't implement splice's specification as it doesn't modify the passed array but returns a new one. As previously answered, modifying an array in Java isn't possible (and using a list is the smart and fast best practice).

Comment: I want this as a library. Thanks :)

Comment: @msangel, I've updated the answer with a maven artifact you can reference as a dependency.

Answer (score 4):

Java arrays have a fixed length, so there's no such method.

You could imagine writing a utility function similar to splice in Java but it would return a different array. There's no point in having arrays in java if you resize them: it's not efficient and you can't share the instance.

The usual and clean solution is to use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which is a resizeable collection. [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), the most commonly used List implementation is backed by an array but is efficient as the array isn't changed every time you resize the collection.

Comment: Now I'm thinking about `substring()` method. We'll see.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis What's the relation with `substring` ?

Comment: I can convert `Array` to `String`, then `substring()` and create `Array`. But not effective way..

Answer (score 0):

**In standard Java libraries, there is no equivalent functionality.**

There is `java.util.Arrays` class, but no similar functionality there.

Answer (score 0):

I misread your question and mixed up `splice` and `slice`.

The class `java.util.Arrays` provides some static functions useful when working with arrays. See the official documentation for other functions: **http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html**.

Java's equivalent for `slice` is: `Arrays.copyOfRange(array, from, to)`.

A similar method to `splice` is `addAll` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-int-java.util.Collection-). But you need to use a `java.util.ArrayList` instead an array and it is not possible to remove elements with it. You would have to provide the elements as another collection, e.g. an `ArrayList`. So it is equivalent to calling `splice(index, 0, element1, element2, ...)`

Comment: No it's not. He is talking about mutation, this will create copy of the array.

Comment: No, this returns a new array. The interesting point in `splice` is that it changes the source array.

Comment: I assumed this `splice`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp and it does not change the array it is called upon but returns a new array.

Comment: I like this method, will try soon.

Comment: But `splice` method can also add to `Array`, make it larger... So I think the only way is to work with `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays have a fixed length, so this cannot be done directly.

If you want to combine two arrays, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80503/4428462).

If you want to add to the array, you should use a `List` or an `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java have a fixed number of elements. But you can make that element null like this:

array[element]==null;

And that is the same as removing it from the array. You can also have a variable that keeps track of how many elements aren't null, so that you can even have an array.length kind of thing that follows that. that's what I do anyway.