# How to concatenate the arrays at the end of the loop

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

I have created two class in Java. The main class 'Main' is used to pass array values into the second class 'Plan'. My code looks something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.utils.Arras;

public class Main {

    public enum State {
        A,
        D,
        H
    };

    Plan[] plan= new Plan[] {
             new Plan(new State[]{State.A, State.A, State.A}),
             new Plan(new State[]{State.A, State.D, State.H})};
}
```

My other class 'Plan' looks like this:

```
import java.utils.Arrays;

public class Plan {

    public static Main.State[] input;
    public static Main.State[] output;
    public static Main.State[] input_new = new Main.State[4];

    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
    this.input_new = input_new;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input_new[i] = input[i];
    }
}
```

Now at the end of the loop I want to append the arrays so that it prints a single array which is

> A A A A D H.

I tried using [this]/[How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)) method, but it gives me an eeror saying 'ArrayUtils' cannot be resolved. Can somebody kindly point out my mistake here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For using arrayutils you need to have apache jar in path.

Comment: Can you put a working example. This code will not compile and we don't really know where the `for loop` is located in your actual code.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Apache Commons Dependency? `ArrayUtils` is not part of the JDK.

How you do this depends on your build tooling. Please Google how you add JAR dependencies to the tooling you are using.

Comment: @Thank you for that response. I doenload the jre and added it in my path, but I am not sure on th libraray name I should use to call it via the 'import'. Could you please tell me the lib name. Thank you :)

Comment: It should be ```org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils```. Your IDE should actually provide you with autocompletion if you just write ```ArrayUtils``` in your code and the JAR file is on the class path.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(arr1), Arrays.stream(arr2)).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `ArrayUtils` belongs to [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library. Follow the link to get the jar and include in your classpath.

Comment: @Thank you for that response. I doenload the jre and added it in my path, but I am not sure on th libraray name I should use to call it via the 'import'. Could you please tell me the lib name. Thank you :)

Comment: `import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`apache.commons`](https://commons.apache.org/) API for `ArraysUtils`

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer you are relating to states, ArrayUtils is a class of the [Apache Commons library](http://commons.apache.org/). You can either add the dependency to your project, or use [one of the manual approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80503/2526920) which are also posted in the same thread than the answer that you used.