# How to Concatenate arrays from a different class in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

I am a beginner at Java. I have created a main program with the main class . This is called `Main.java`. THis main class contains a set of arrays. These arrays are imported into the second class called the `Test.java`. Now I am looking for a method to concatenate all the arrays at the end of this second class. My code looks as shown below:

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 public class Main{

      public enum State{A,D,H};

      Test[] tests = new Test[]{
               new Test(new State[]{State.A, State.H, State.A, State.H}),
               new Test(new State[]{State.A, State.H, State.A, State.D}),
               new Test(new State[]{State.H, State.D, State.A, State.A})
       };
```

The calss Test.java looks like this :

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    public class Test{

    public static Main.State[] in;
    public static Main.State[] in_state= new Main.State[4];
    public static String data_in;

    Test(Main.State[] in){
        this in = in;
        this.in_state=in_state;

    for( int i=0; i<in.length; i++){
        in_state[i]=in[i];
        data_in =java.util.Arrays.toString(in_state);
        data_in = data_in.replaceAll(",", "");
        data_in = data_in.replaceAll(" ","");}
   System.out.println( "The input arrays are" +data_in) ;
```

Now the output I get looks like this :

```
    The input arrays are[AHAH]
    The input arrays are[AHAD]
    The input arrays are[HDAA]
```

Instead of this I want to get it as **AHAHAHADHDAA**. I tried using the `ArrayUtils.addAll` function but the program stops executing abruptly. Could somebody please help me out. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: may be a duplicate and this helps you to concat arrays: [duplicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Comment: I'd advise you to consider using `ArrayList`s instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do too many things in the same place, the constructor for class `Test`.

Leave the assignment of initial state to the constructor. Put the merging code in a separate method and put the code to convert to `String` also in a separate method.

Also, members of Test should not be static, otherwise the get mixed up.

This would be the corrected code following those advices :

Main.java

```
public class Main
{

    public static enum State
    {

        A, D, H
    };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test[] tests = new Test[]
        {
            new Test(new State[]
            {
                State.A, State.H, State.A, State.H
            }),
            new Test(new State[]
            {
                State.A, State.H, State.A, State.D
            }),
            new Test(new State[]
            {
                State.H, State.D, State.A, State.A
            })
        };
        Test testMerged = Test.merge(tests);
        System.out.println("The input arrays are" + testMerged);
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
public class Test
{

    static Main.State[] in;

    public static Test merge(Test[] tests)
    {
        int size = calculateSize( tests );
        Main.State[] state = new Main.State[size];
        int i = 0;
        for ( Test test : tests )
        {
            for ( Main.State s : test.in )
                state[i++] = s;
        }
        return new Test( state );
    }

    private static int calculateSize(Test[] tests)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for ( Test test : tests )
        {
            for ( Main.State s : test.in )
                ++result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    Test(Main.State[] in)
    {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String result =java.util.Arrays.toString(in);
        result = result.replaceAll(",", "");
        result = result.replaceAll(" ","");
        return result;
    }
}
```