# How to connect two different arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

If I have one array of names, and one array of lap times, how would I link the two arrays so I can sort the times and still keep the associated names? 
this is what the two arrays look like:

```
String[] names = { "Paul", "Dan", "Hayden", "Sam", "Pauline"};
    int[] times = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445 };
```

As of now, I run a selection sort algorithm to get lowest times to highest but i cant figure out how to keep paul connected to 341.

I do NOT want to concatenate the two arrays, I want to be able to sort the times array and then call the name associated with the particular time.

Comment: It depends. You either want a `List` of a custom class of objects or you want a `Map`.

Comment: Why dont you write a class which will have name and time and you have the array of that class objects.

Comment: it is a hw assignment, the professor gave us these two arrays as inputs. i dont think he wants us changing this part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Sort the time array and swap position of element in both the array together, in that way when ever swap happens it will maintain the link between times and names array, here is the program for that, I did sorting in descending Order

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] names = { "Paul", "Dan", "Hayden", "Sam", "Pauline"};
        int[] times = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445 };
        
        
        for(int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < times.length; outerIndex++){
            for(int innerIndex = outerIndex+1;  innerIndex < times.length; innerIndex++){
                if(times[outerIndex]<times[innerIndex]){
                    swap(outerIndex, innerIndex, names, times);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am swaping element position in both the arrays:

```
public static void swap(int outerIndex, int innerIndex, String[] names, int[] times){
        int tempTime;
        String tempName;
        
        tempTime = times[outerIndex];
        tempName = names[outerIndex];
        
        times[outerIndex] = times[innerIndex];
        names[outerIndex] = names[innerIndex];
        
        times[innerIndex] = tempTime;
        names[innerIndex] = tempName;
    }
```

**Input:**

> String[] names = { "Paul", "Dan", "Hayden", "Sam", "Pauline"};
>
> int[] times = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445 };

**Output:**

> String[] names = {"Pauline", "Paul", "Sam", "Hayden", "Dan"};
>
> int[] times = { 445, 341, 329, 278, 273};

Answer (score 0):

Please sort with array room. for example

```
names[0] = "Paul"
times [0] = 341
```

something like that

Comment: can you explain more? i do not know what you mean sort with array room.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the **names** and **times** arrays as-is and use a third array that contains indexes into the other two:

```
 String[] names = { "Paul", "Dan", "Hayden", "Sam", "Pauline"};
    int[] times = { 341, 273, 278, 329, 445 };
    int[] index = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Run your sort algorithm on **names** or **times** (depending on how you want to sort). When you run the algorithm, access the **times** array (for example) via the **index** array:

```
times[index[x]]; // where x is whatever index you are on during your sort
```

When you find you need to swap two items, do the swap operation on the index array:

```
swap(index[0], index[1]);
```

Once the sorting algorithm is completed, the **names** and **times** arrays remain associated via their array positions but if you access them via the **index** array they will be accessed in sorted order.

p.s. I feel dirty doing your school work for you :)

Comment: is the swap operation from java.util.arrays? 

honestly this homework was more about creating a sorting algorithm. If my prof hadn't already given us this code I was planning on using a 2D array (I did that on the last hw and it worked really well) and sorting on times.

Comment: also @crchurchey, when you say access the times array via the index array, you meant to type  times[index[x]] rather than names[index[x]], right?

Comment: **swap** is generic; if implemented it just exchanges the items de-referenced by index[0] and index[1]. Many sorting algorithms use something similar.

Comment: So the prof is just having you implement a function? Does it have a return type or are you supposed to just print the arrays in order?