# im trying to randomly select elements from 3 array of Strings?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to randomly select elements from 3 array of Strings?

```
private static String[] one   ={"dog, cat"};
private static String[] two   ={"ate, ran"};
private static String[] three ={"away, some}"

Random words = new Random();
int index=words.nextInt(one.length+two.length+three.length);

System.out.println(one[index]);
```

Comment: What do you think `words.nextInt(one.length+two.length+three.length);` does or should do and why do you think so?

Comment: Are you trying to pick one random element from any of the three arrays or one random element from each of the three arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the program is that you're getting a random number between 0 and 6 and then using this random number as an index to get a value from only the first array. There are two problems here,

1. one[index] will cause an arrayindexoutofboundsexception in some cases because the max index for one is 1 when index can also be 2,3,4, or 5.
2. also, the objective is to get a random element from THREE arrays of strings, not just one

My suggestion is getting a random number between one and three (inclusive) to choose one of the string arrays, then find a random number between 0 and the chosen array's length. And assign that to the index of the chosen array.

Answer (score 0):

A two step approach is probably best:

1. Combine all your arrays into one larger array. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java) demonstrates several ways to accomplish this. For example, try this method (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80503/3761440)):

   ```
   public String[] concat(String[] a, String[] b) {
       int aLen = a.length;
       int bLen = b.length;
       String[] c= new String[aLen + bLen];
       System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
       System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);
       return c;
   }

   // use it like this
   String[] combined = concat(concat(one, two), three);
   ```
2. Pick a random element from the combined array, and print it:

   ```
   int index = r.nextInt(combined.length);
   System.out.println(combined[index]);
   ```