# How to combine arrays into one array in while loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, pojo

I have a stream of strings from a csv file. These strings are converted to arrays and must be put in an Object's setter and the Object in a hashMap as a value. How do i concatenate all comming Arrays into one and only then use the Set method? Is there any better solution than concatenating the arrays before the set method?

Here is my code:

```
HashMap<Integer, Publication> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
try {

        CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(filename);

        csv.readHeaders();

        while (csv.readRecord()) { 
            int id = Integer.parseInt(csv.get("ID"));             
            Publication pub = new Publication();
            String names = csv.get("Names");
            String[] namesArr = names.split(",");                
            if (!innerMap.containsKey(id)) {
                innerMap.put(id, new Publication());
            } 
            String[] merged = ????
            pub.setNames(merged);
            innerMap.put(au.getIdx(), pub);
        }
        csv.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `String[] merged = ????`

Comment: It is maybe where i should merge all coming arrays before the set method

Comment: is this concatinating the arrays together, or sorting while merging, or what?

Comment: eventualy i need to remove duplicates. but concatinating is my main goal.

Comment: where is `Authors` coming from?  I just see a `.split` but i dont know where that is defined.

Comment: sorry it was meant to be names not authors. i've changed it

Comment: checking, lets see what your angle is

Comment: let us say i am getting at first one array of names for the first id, then another array for the same id.. how can i use your concat method in the first loop?

Comment: take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Store them in a `List` first:

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>;
...
list.add(namesArr);
```

Then, once you've finished reading:

```
int size = 0;
for (String[] arr : list) {
   size += arr.length;
}
List<String> all = new ArrayList<>(size);
for (String[] arr : list) {
  all.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
}
```

The first loop helps to allocate the necessary memory to hold all of the data (otherwise there may be lots of reallocations and array copying in the `ArrayList` internally while you are adding elements to it in the second loop).

Comment: I can't do that. I need to store arrays of specific id's. This is why i am using a hashmap and storing the an object with a concatenated array as a value

Comment: Ok, then just use `Map<Integer, List<String[]>>` to store all of the arrays per id, then just do the above for all of the lists.

Answer (score 1):

this has already been answered using Apache commons - [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Here's a pure java 8 way

```
    String[] arr1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
    String[] arr2 = { "e", "f", "g" };
    Stream<String> stream1 = Stream.of(arr1);
    Stream<String> stream2 = Stream.of(arr2);
    String[] arr = Stream.concat(stream1, stream2).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that if the map key exists, you want to extract the values, append additional values and then put it back in.

I would use a getter, then run this concat function which returns a new array.  Since an Array is capped by its size, you cant grow it unless you make a new array and copy everything over.

to concat 2 string arrays where A comes first:

```
String[] concat( String[] a, String[] b){
  String[] out = new String[a.length + b.length]();
  int i = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
    out[i] = a[j]
    i++;
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
    out[i] = b[j];
    i++;
  }
  return out;
}
```