# Array validation through a while loop

Tags: java, arrays, validation, arraylist, while-loop

I am doing "Rock,Paper,Scissors" game and I want to check if the input matches with any arrays, for now I have this code and it works perfect:

```
String[] rockArray = {"Rock","rock","1"},
         paperArray = {"Paper","paper","2"},
         scissorsArray = {"Scissors","scissors","3"};
String[][] answersArray = {rockArray, paperArray, scissorsArray};

//Scanner
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

// Input
System.out.print("\nRock, Paper or Scissors? -> ");
String answer = scan.next();

 // Checking if the input contains the right values
 while(!Arrays.asList(answerRock).contains(answer) &&
       !Arrays.asList(answerPaper).contains(answer) &&
       !Arrays.asList(answerScissors).contains(answer)) {

         System.out.print("Try again: ");
         answer = scan.next();
 }
```

But I want to make it simple and here is my idea but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
// Here is my arrays 
String[] rockArray = {"Rock","rock","1"},
         paperArray = {"Paper","paper","2"},
         scissorsArray = {"Scissors","scissors","3"};
String[][] globalArray = {rockArray, paperArray, scissorsArray};

// Input
System.out.print("\nRock, Paper or Scissors? -> ");
String answer = scan.next();

//Validation
while(!Arrays.asList(globalArray).contains(answer) {
      System.out.println("Try again: ");
      answer = scan.next();
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code snippet does not work because you can't do something like this `!Arrays.asList(globalArray).contains(answer)`.

One solution is to copy the contents of the three array into your global array like this:

```
String[] rockArray = {"Rock","rock","1"},
         paperArray = {"Paper","paper","2"},
         scissorsArray = {"Scissors","scissors","3"};
String[] globalArray = new String[9];
/* Copy Contents To Global Array */
System.arraycopy(rockArray, 0, globalArray, 0, 3);
System.arraycopy(paperArray, 0, globalArray, 3, 3);
System.arraycopy(scissorsArray, 0, globalArray, 6, 3);
```

Now you can do this:

```
while(!Arrays.asList(globalArray).contains(answer)) {
    System.out.println("Try again: ");
    answer = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Right, that's why I am asking if there are any other ways to do it?

Comment: in this case, if I enter "test", I will get an infinite loop and it won't except the correct input

Comment: That's because it should be `scan.nextLine()` and not just `scan.next()`. It works perfectly. Check here: http://ideone.com/kB4U3n

Comment: @S.Anthony Your Welcome! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
String[][] globalArray = {rockArray, paperArray, scissorsArray};
...
Arrays.asList(globalArray)
```

This call to `Arrays.asList()` will create list with 3 elements, the 3 array and not a list with the content of the arrays. When you then use `contains` to search for the element, you will always get `false` because `answer` will never be on of the arrays (how would it, it's a `String` not an array).

I suggest you do something like this:

```
List<String> allAnswers = Arrays.asList(rockArray);
allAnswers.addAll(Arrays.asList(paperArray));
allAnswers.addAll(Arrays.asList(scissorsArray));
...
while(!allAnswers.contains(answer)) {
  ...
```

This also saves you from calling `Arrays.asList()` over and over again which improves performance.

Answer (score 1):

`!Arrays.asList(globalArray).contains(answer)` doesn't work because the `Arrays.asList(...)` method will output a `List<String[]>` not `List<String>`.

If you really want to use `asList(...)` you have to input an `String[] allPossibleInputString`