# Initialize new array out of 2 known arrays

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

how do i initialize a new array out of known arrays?

e.g.

```
char[] word1 = new char[]{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
char[] word2 = new char[]{'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
char[] newArray;
```

so how do i initialize newArray out of word1 and word2?

thanks.

Comment: Assuming you want to join the two into a single array, take a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the new array and copy the values using [`System.arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)).

```
char[] word1 = new char[]{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
char[] word2 = new char[]{'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
char[] newArray = new char[word1.length + word2.length];
System.arraycopy(word1, 0, newArray, 0, word1.length);
System.arraycopy(word2, 0, newArray, word1.length, word2.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to initialize newArray:

```
char[] newArray = ArrayUtils.addAll(word1, word2);
```

This should do it.

Comment: i tried it this way but i need to type it in in my university's website and it tells me its wrong. are there any other solutions? it should be a newbie solution.

Comment: If there is another way then I don't know it. But you can store it in `List` if you want.