# How do I add two different arrays and print the result?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I had to make an array that counted the seating in a movie theater, the second class m2 represents another showtime. I do not know how to add both arrays together and print the result of the sum of these two arrays.

This the MovieSeats tester file:

```
public class MovieSeatsTester
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MovieSeats m = new MovieSeats(3,3);
        MovieSeats m2 = new MovieSeats(3,3);
        m.seating(0,0);
        m.seating(0,1);
        m.seating(1,0);
        m.seating(2,2);
        m.seating(2,2);
        m2.seating(0,0);
        m2.seating(0,0);
        m.print();
        m.reset();
        m2.print();
        m2.reset();
    }
}
```

This is the MovieSeats file:

```
public class MovieSeats
{
    private int attendance[][];

    public MovieSeats()
    {
    }

    public MovieSeats(int rows, int columns)
    {
        attendance = new int[rows][columns];        
    }

    public void seating(int r, int c)
    {   
        attendance[r][c] += 1;
    }

    public void print()
    {
    for (int r = 0; r < attendance.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < attendance.length; c++)
        {
            System.out.println("At row " + r + " col " + c + ", There are " +   attendance[r][c] + " Sitting here.");
        } 

    }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void reset()
    {
    for (int r = 0; r < attendance.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < attendance.length; c++)
        {
            attendance[r][c] = 0;
        } 
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add two different arrays"? You also might want to work on writing a [mcve]. A lot of the code here isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: Use the reset method you wrote as a guide to generate your sum, e.g. sum = sum + attendance[r][c]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "add two different arrays" you mean "create a third array where each element in the third array is the sum of the corresponding element of each of the first two arrays."

## 1. Access Each Array

In order to add the two arrays together, you would first need access to each array somehow.  Since the `attendance` field is `private`, you should add a getter method for it to the `MovieSeats` class.

Get `attendance` without encapsulation:

```
public int[][] getAttendance() {
    return attendance;
}
```

Get `attendance` with encapsulation:

```
public int[][] getAttendance() {
    int rows = attendance.length();
    int cols = attendance[0].length();
    int[][] copy = new int[rows][cols];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            copy[i][j]=current[i][j];

    return copy;
}
```

## 2. Add Two Arrays Element-Wise

Next, once you have access to both arrays in the same place (probably inside your `main`), you would then have to add them together.  I would recommend putting the result in a third array.  The most rudimentary way of adding these two arrays is the following:

```
int[][] attendance1 = m.getAttendance();
int[][] attendance2 = m2.getAttendance();
int[][] sum = new int[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        sum[i][j] = attendance1[i][j] + attendance2[i][j];
```

Then, you could print the total attendance by seat with the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        System.out.printf("Total Attendance for seat (%d,%d): %d\n",
                i, j, sum[i][j]);
```

---

Now, if instead what you want to do is to sum all of the elements of both arrays into a single value, then you would do the following.

## Sum An Array

```
int sum = 0;

int[][] attendance1 = m.getAttendance();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        sum += attendance1[i][j];

int[][] attendance2 = m2.getAttendance();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        sum += attendance2[i][j];
```

Comment: How do I print out the total attendance for all the seats. For example at (0,0) in attendance 1 it is 3 then in attendance 2 it is 2 and I want to print 5 since that is the total for that seat.

Comment: @Susamp Glad it works!  Please make sure to upvote my answer, too

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following method to the MovieSeat class:

```
public int sum() {
    int result = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < attendance.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < attendance.length; c++) {
            result += attendance[r][c];
        }            
    }
    return result;
}
```

And the call the `sum` method and find the total sum in the `main` method:

```
MovieSeats m = new MovieSeats(3, 3);
MovieSeats m2 = new MovieSeats(3, 3);
m.seating(0, 0);
m.seating(0, 1);
m.seating(1, 0);
m.seating(2, 2);
m.seating(2, 2);
m2.seating(0, 0);
m2.seating(0, 0);
m.print();

System.out.println("sum: " + m.sum());
System.out.println("---");

m2.print();
System.out.println("sum: " + m2.sum());

System.out.println("total sum: " + (m.sum() + m2.sum()));
m.reset();
m2.reset();
```

Note to reset after you call the `sum` method.

Comment: in the line System.out.println("At row " + r + " col " + c + ", There are " +   attendance[r][c] + " Sitting here.") in my MovieSeats class, it tells me how many people are sitting in a specific seat. In the total sum how would I print that line were it tells how many people have ever sat in that specific seat?