# Call a class in other activity and change one of its variable

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a simple game, I have 3 levels. I'm done with the level1 in activity1. But since the code will be the same in level2 except only one variable, I wanted to extends the level1 class in activity2(level2), but my class is already extending Activity class and  in java there no way to inherit two class simultaneously, so I decided to to create an object of the class in activity2(level2) and to initialize it in onCreate () , but there's one issue I'm facing, I have a string array variable which contains 100 words in level1 , I want to add another 100 to that string to make it 200 in level2. How can I do that. I don't want to copy the entire code of level 1 in level2 and after to just change the variable, it's redundancy, a bad practice.

Here's a prototype of what I mean.

Activity 1 , level1.  and underneath Activity2 , leve2

```
  public class Level1 extends Activity {
      String words[ ] = {ball, game, food, bike, ...... ..}
        //100  words
          protected void on create(Bundle b){
          super.onCreate(b);
          setContentView(R.layout. level1)

             }
          }



     public class level2 extends Activity{
        Level1 level;
         protected void onCreate (Bundle b){
         super.onCreate(b);
         setContentView(R.layout.level2);
         level = new Level1();
           //how can l add 100 more word in the string arrived 
              here
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate the data (words) from the UI (Activity) first. Create a class that is responsible for providing the data for the Activities.

```
public class WordsProvider {

    private String wordsForLevel1[] = {ball, game, food, bike, ...... ..};
    private String wordsForLevel2[] = {words, you, want, to, add, to, first, array};

    public String[] getWordsForLevel1() {
        return wordsForLevel1;
    }

    public String[] getWordsForLevel2() {
        return concat(wordsForLevel1, wordsForLevel2);
    }
}
```

(concat method can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4552278/3010690))

Now, you don't have to couple your Activities. Instantiating an Activity manually is not recommended, let the Android System do that work. So your code will look like this:

```
public class Level1 extends Activity {
    String words[];

    protected void on create(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.level1)
        words = new WordsProvider().getWordsForLevel1();
    }
}

public class Level2 extends Activity {
     String words[];

     protected void onCreate (Bundle b) {
         super.onCreate(b);
         setContentView(R.layout.level2);
         words = new WordsProvider().getWordsForLevel2();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps for you!