# Concatenating two int[]

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

There are easy solutions for concatenating two `String[]` or `Integer[]` in java by `Streams`. Since `int[]` is frequently used. Is there any straightforward way for concatenating two `int[]`?

Here is my thought:

```
int[] c = {1, 34};
int[] d = {3, 1, 5};
Integer[] cc = IntStream.of(c).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
Integer[] dd = Arrays.stream(d).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
int[] m = Stream.concat(Stream.of(cc), Stream.of(dd)).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m));

>>
[1, 34, 3, 1, 5]
```

It works, but it actually converts `int[]` to `Integer[]`, then converts `Integer[]` back to `int[]` again.

Comment: There are various solutions for concatenating arrays here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java though they are not specific to ints.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `IntStream.concat` in concert with `Arrays.stream` to get this thing done without any auto-boxing or unboxing. Here's how it looks.

```
int[] result = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(c), Arrays.stream(d)).toArray();
```

Note that `Arrays.stream(c)` returns an `IntStream`, which is then concatenated with the other `IntStream` before collected into an array.

Here's the output.

> [1, 34, 3, 1, 5]

Answer (score 20):

You can simply concatenate primitive(`int`) streams using `IntStream.concat` as:

```
int[] m = IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(c), IntStream.of(d)).toArray();
```

Comment: Just reads better in my opinion, though notably, the `IntStream.of` under the hood makes use of the `Arrays.stream` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use for loops, to avoid using toArray().

```
int[] e = new int[c.length+d.length];
int eIndex = 0;
for (int index = 0; index < c.length; index++){
    e[eIndex] = c[index];
    eIndex++;
}
for (int index = 0; index < d.length; index++){
    e[eIndex] = d[index];
    eIndex++;
}
```

Comment: No need to implement such loops by hand. Just use `int[] e = Arrays.copyOf(c, c.length+d.length); System.arraycopy(d, 0, e, c.length, d.length);` and you’re done.