# ArrayStoreException when concatenating two arrays Stream

Tags: java, java-8

I was following this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864223/concatenating-two-int) and was trying to get a new way of concatenating two arrays.

```
int[] c = {1, 34};
int[] d = {3, 1, 5};
```

---

**I came up with this:**

```
 Integer [] res= Stream.of(c, d)
                .flatMap(Stream::of)
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Above compiles fine but i get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.stream.SpinedBuffer.copyInto(SpinedBuffer.java:194)
    at java.util.stream.Nodes$SpinedNodeBuilder.copyInto(Nodes.java:1290)
    at java.util.stream.SpinedBuffer.asArray(SpinedBuffer.java:215)
    at java.util.stream.Nodes$SpinedNodeBuilder.asArray(Nodes.java:1296)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:439)
```

What is my mistake, and please give a explanation so that i can understand the concept.

PS: I have seen [Dealing with an ArrayStoreException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369957/dealing-with-an-arraystoreexception) and believe that my question consists of stream which are incompitable types that is why they are not getting stored, so two questions are different.

Comment: Your arrays are primitive arrays (`int[]`) while you want to concatenate them to a wrapper class array (`Integer[]::new`)  - I'd say autoboxing doesn't work here.

Comment: I think you just misunderstood the explanation, as you have just answered your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stream.of` treats the input array as a single element. Use `Arrays.stream()` instead.

```
int[] c = {1, 34};
int[] d = {3, 1, 5};

int[] res= Stream.of(c, d)
  .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
  .toArray();

  for (int re : res) {
      System.out.println(re);
  }
```

Result:

```
1
34
3
1
5
```

---

If you want to have it boxed, go for:

```
Integer[] res= Stream.of(c, d)
  .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).boxed()
  .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: when i do `Arrays.stream()` in Intellij compiler , then compiler gives me hint that `Arrays.stream()` can be written as `Stream.of()` , so whats make the difference?

Comment: @CommonMan are you trying my example? there are two signatures of Stream.of and compiler can infer the wrong one if it's put in a different context

Comment: what is the significance of `flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)` , will it not just return array stream?

Comment: sir i am trying your example.

Comment: then I'd consider it a bug... but it doesn't happen in my IDEA 2018.3.4

Comment: if I replace it manually with Stream.of, it doesn't compile - I'd trust javac on this one

Comment: understood, need more practice, till now i got what you all said.

Comment: Even if it worked, replacing the idiomatic `Arrays.stream` to *stream* over an *array* with the `Stream.of` method which just happens to accept an array due to the way, *varargs* have been implemented in Java, is a really poor advice. That trick would work if you used `IntStream.of`, for the same reasons `Stream.of` works with arrays of objects, still, there is no reason to replace `Arrays.stream`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Stream.of(c, d)
```

is a `Stream<int[]>`. You can't store `int[]` elements in an `Integer[]`.

Use `IntStream.concat` instead:

```
IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(c), IntStream.of(d)).boxed()
   .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: I saw many answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864223/concatenating-two-int but i wanna do something different, so i tried, please suggest how can i build upon my approach?

Answer (score 3):

`.flatMap(Stream::of)` on a `Stream<int[]>` returns a `Stream<int[]>` (Since `Stream.of(int[])` will execute `Stream<T> of(T t)` and not `Stream<T> of(T... values)`). Therefore these elements cannot be stored in an `Integer[]` array.

You can work with `IntStream`s instead:

```
int [] res= Stream.of(c, d)
                  .flatMapToInt (IntStream::of)
                  .toArray();
```