# Is recursion possible with different return and parameter types

Tags: java, recursion, return

I have a method signature where the return type is an String array and the parameter is a String. I have to break the string passed to the method into substrings of length 3, and return an array containing all the substrings as elements.
this has too be done recursively.

However the method signature I am given has a different return type than parameter, so is it possible for recursion to work under these conditions:

```
private String[] substrings(String string) {...
```

Comment: Yes, that’s normal, it’s no problem.

Comment: Yes, though recursion often works through helper functions. The first function sets up the parameters and then calls the helper function which works recursively. But your function is one that would work recursively.

Comment: Ok i see. I am trying to break down the String passed to the method into substrings of length 3, then return an array of substrings as elements recursively, can't work out where to start

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is, why wouldn't it be? The parameter type(s) and the return type(s) have no relationship with each other.

Here is an example of an event processor, which doesn't even have a return type:

```java
void processEvent(Event e) {
    // do something with the event

    processEvent(getNextEvent())
}

processEvent(getNextEvent());
```

Here is an example of a Fibonacci series generator which has different parameter (number) and return (array of numbers) types:

```java
long[] fibonacci(long n) {
    if (n == 0) return new long[] { 1 };
    if (n == 1) return new long[] { 1, 1 };

    long[] a = fibonacci(n);
    long[] b = fibonacci(n-1);

    long[] both = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + b.length);
    return System.arraycopy(b, 0, both, a.length, b.length);
}
```

For your example, it would look something like this:

```java
// Pseudocode only !!!
String[] substrings(String s) {
    if (s.size <= 3) return new String[] { s };
    return (new String[] { s.slice(0, 3) }).concat(substrings(s.slice(3)));
}
```

Comment: Whoa. Didn't think [concatenating two arrays was that complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49772469/2988). I'm so glad I don't know Java.

Comment: In fairness, most of the times you're not working with arrays in Java. And most of the times if you do *need* an array, you can just pass through a List or a Stream to get there. The vast majority of times you have "a bunch of something" in Java, it's some form of Collection. Maybe not *as* memory efficient but arrays are extreme micro optimisation when you have the JVM already running and (potentially) taking up more memory than your program.