# Java - TextFlow how to add list of strings? One after each other?

Tags: java, textflow

let's say I have this example, how to add it, so that it could be displayed later on with gui inside textflow window? :

```
List<String> Test1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

List<String> Test2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
```

Output should be like: ("actual output, each on a new line")

1. `Line = "a1";`
2. `Line = "b2";`
3. `Line = "c3";`

How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do this answer you question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Comment: Not really, because I also need to change font, color and italic and that could be done only in textflow. So I have to create a textflow , not an array where I put everything together, that would now work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
String[] Test1 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
String[] Test2 = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

public void main(String[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Test1.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Line = \"" + Test1[i] + Test2[i] + "\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes like this, but this in textflow does now work.... as every string has to have different font, color, italic. I can't just get them together.