# How to merge two arrays into a new array

Tags: java

I would like to make a sum of 2 arrays.
I don't know where is the mistake.
here is the code:

```
    public static int[] Arr(int a[], int b[]) {
    System.out.println(a[] + b[]);
    return a[] + b[];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the sum of two arrays"? What's the expected output?

Comment: Have the arrays the same length?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Comment: @sp00m can you add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java as the correct dup?

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants something like this :

```
public static int[] Arr(int a[], int b[]) {

    int[] sum = new int[a.length + b.length];

    for (int i = 0; i<a.length;i++) {
        sum[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (int i = a.length; i<a.length + b.length;i++) {
        sum[i] = b[i-a.length];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: thank you bro! this is what i meant!
but it gives me an error to "Arrays.toString
it tells me that ARRAY CANNOT BE RESOLVED

Comment: You have to import java.util.Arrays in the first lines of your code

Comment: thank yoy so much  guys!

Comment: sorry i'm new. how can i do it to accept ur answer?

Comment: There is a tick symbol at the right of the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work