# How do I add an array into an arraylist (so that it becomes a 2D arraylist) in java?

Tags: java

I have an array:

```
String[] a = {"abc","def","ghi"}
```

Now I want to store this array into my string arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

so that it becomes like this:

```
[["abc","def","ghi"]]
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
arr.add(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Please help me

Comment: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Comment: `ArrayList<String[]> arr = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: And then `arr.add(a);`

Comment: Unless you're looking for `List<List<String>>`

Comment: In what sense does what you're doing "not work". What exactly are you expecting, and what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Arrays.asList(a) returns List, to add it to your list you need to use addAll()

```
arr.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
```

Instead of

```
arr.add(Arrays.asList(a));
```

But the result will be ["abc","def","ghi"]

If you want to achieve this [["abc","def","ghi"]] then define your ArrayList as

```
List<List<String>> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

using arralist addAll() method we can do but,
Using arrayList is depricated approach , use Streams instead of it:

```
System.out.println(Collections.singletonList(Stream.of(new String[] {"abc","def","ghi"}).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

will result in:

[[abc, def, ghi]]