# Adding a zero byte to the start of a binary hash?

Tags: java, cryptography

For this question I am asked to:

1. convert text to hash,
2. then put it into a byte array,
3. construct a new byte array 0b, with a zero byte at index 0 then b.

I am able to get the hash of the message `c84291b88e8367ef3448899117f8b497f58ac7d43689239783f708ea0092c39b` with my code:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    
    //Convert Message to hash
md.update(message1.getBytes());
byte[] digest = md.digest();
String Hash = hexaToString(digest);
System.out.println( "Message 1 in hash is = " + Hash);
```

And I am able to convert it into a byte array but I am not sure how to add the zerobyte to the start of the byte array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I concatenate two arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Comment: Create a new byte array `byte[] temp = new byte[1 + digest.length]` and use `System.arraycopy(digest, 0, temp, 1, digest.length)`

Answer (score 2):

When computing the digest, you can provide an output array via an overloaded form of [`digest()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#digest-byte:A-int-int-). You can allocate an extra byte, and store whatever you like in the extra space at the beginning.

```java
int len = md.getDigestLength();
byte[] digest = new byte[len + 1];
md.digest(digest, 1, len);
```

Comment: Note that Java automatically sets all bytes to zero during allocation, so there is no need to set the byte to zero explicitly.